# Git feature branch verification

Tags: git, build-process, release-management

Is there any way to verify base of git branch?
To implement concurrent versions, we are using git tagging mechanism. 
So Developers should use specific version tag to created bug fix branches like:
git branch -b "UAT bug fix" v3.0.0

Git flow Diagram:

[image]
I am looking for a way to capture the bug fix branch which is not created using a tag.

Comment: Well I guess this is not possible due to the fact that git does not track informations about the commit a branch started off. Maybe it's possible with a lot of scripting and shell magic but it's not that easy as you might suspected it is.

Comment: agree, with 'gitk' and 'git log' I can verify it visually . However it looks like it is difficult to have an automated mechanism to handle it.

I found a relevant post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161204/find-the-parent-branch-of-a-git-branch , but it's not working for tag based branches.

Comment: I am not sure if I have understood the question. You want to find the first commit that was created in a specific branch?

Comment: @Bustikiller : No, I am not looking for branch point.
I've posted a git branching strategy for your perusal. I am looking for a mechanism to identify branches which are not created using version tag.