# Find out which repository was used to create a branch

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

Is there a way to find out which branch was used to create a branch from in Sourcetree or GIT?

Comment: Your comment on Yasser's answer seems to be different than your question.  Can you add some additional clarification about what you're trying to do?

Comment: @BJ Myers I created a branch called BranchB from a branch called BranchA. I did this a while ago and I have forgotten which branch I used to create BranchB. My question is how do I find out the name of BranchA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to find out the parent branch that you stemmed from, you can take a look at [this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161204/find-the-parent-branch-of-a-git-branch), seems to have all the different answers for this.

I'm on Windows, so I tried this and it worked for me using PowerShell:

```
git show-branch -a | where-object { $_.Contains('*') -eq $true} | Where-object{$_.Contains($branchName) -ne $true } | select -first 1 | % {$_ -replace('.*\[(.*)\].*','$1')} | % { $_ -replace('[\^~].*','') }
```

Make sure to replace $branchName with whatever the current branch name is, or set it in advance before running the command.

If you're on `bash` there are also lots of answers in there that use `grep` and `sed` and other `bash` utilities to do this same parsing of the `git show-branch` command output.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

`git remote -v` gives you the remote repo.

Comment: Hi @Yasser Elsayed my remote repo name is the same as my local branch. I'm trying to find out what branch I used to create this branch.

Comment: @ClintonGreen I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do. A repo is not the same as a branch. `git remote -v` gives you the address of the remote repo. If you want to get the name of the remote branch you're tracking, `git status` shows you that, says something like `Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/branch_name'.`

Comment: Hi I think I used the wrong terminology. I'm looking for the name of the branch used to create the current branch I am working in. Thanks

Comment: If you used the wrong terminology, then edit your question.

Comment: I added another answer that I think covers your updated question.