# Finding specific directory names under a directory structure recursively?

Tags: git

We have the below branch structure in git repository. I know how to find the specific files in git repository matching some pattern. But I'm not able to find the command which would give me - e.g. (BranchStatDir_N is created in BranchDev02 branch which is in master branch)

```
> master
> > > > ---BranchDev01
> > > > > > > > --BranchDir_1

> > > > > > > > --BranchDir_2

> > > > > > > > --BranchDir_3

> > > > > > > > -- ....

> > > > > > > > -- ....

> > > > > > > > --BranchDir_N

> > > > ---BranchDev02

> > > > > > > > --01XXXStatDir_1

> > > > > > > > --02YYYStatDir_2

> > > > > > > > --03ZZZStatDir_3

> > > > > > > > -- ....

> > > > > > > > -- ....

> > > > > > > > --BranchStatDir_N

> > > > ---BranchDev03

> > > > > > > > --6ed.BranchModeDir_1

> > > > > > > > --MAK.BranchModeDir_2

> > > > > > > > --RKenBranchModeDir_3

> > > > > > > > -- ....

> > > > > > > > -- ....

> > > > > > > > --BranchModeDir_N
```

Given a directory, how can I find a specific directory in the Git repository, walking down all directories recursively? Is there any way we can walk through the specific directory in git repository structure under all branches?

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up branches and folders. The former is not the latter (contrary to Subversion, where branches and tags are folders)

And branches are not "structured" that way: a branch can be rebased/renamed/reset at any time.
See "[Find the parent branch of a git branch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3161204/6309)"