# trying to find parent branch of current git branch?

Tags: git

I'm trying to identify the parent branch of the current git branch that I'm working in.  I googled this a bit and I had a hard time finding a straightforward answer. Can you please provide a simple git command that will provide this information?  This seems like a pretty basic user requirement.  What is the simplest way to do this?  Looking for the abridged version and I don't care about weird scenarios.  Just trying to get some traction on this for now. If the git command is not straightforward then is there any type of gui tool that may help provide a simplified view of this problem?

Comment: Can you define "parent branch"?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that I created my current branch off of the develop branch but I'm looking for a way to verify that

Comment: That should be a duplicate of the question with the velociraptor answer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3161204/6309