# Can git know which branch your current branch was branched from?

Tags: git, bash, alias

I'd like to create a git alias that lets me sync my branch from the original branch it was branched from.

For example, if I branched from `<branch A>`, is there a way for a git alias to recognize that it needs to pull from `origin/<branch A>` in order to sync?

Comment: Is `origin/<branch A>` the parent branch?

Comment: Yes. `origin/<branch A>` would be the parent branch of `<local branch>`. So running the alias would merge `<origin/branch A>` into `<local branch>`.

Comment: Why not a simple merge from `<origin/branch A>` when present in `<local branch>`?

Comment: That's what I'm doing currently, but the place I work has fairly lengthy branch name prefixes, so if there was a way to just use `git sync` instead of `git merge origin/<branch A>`, it would be convenient.

Comment: `git` doesn't really have any way to do this in general. You might be able to do it in certain limited cases if you make assumptions about branch origins. But, given arbitrary branches `A` and `B`, all `git` can really say about them is either they have one or more common ancestors, or they do not - there's nothing stored about whether `A` was branched from `B` or whether `B` was branched from `A`, or maybe both were branched from `C`, which has since been deleted...

Comment: Ah. That's too bad. Thanks for the response.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161204/find-the-parent-branch-of-a-git-branch

Answer (score 5):

Git does not know or care how a *branch name*, like `master` or `feature-31415` or `ourDevelopmentProcessUsesReallyLongBranchNamesBecauseTheyHateUs`, came about.  All it knows or cares about is that the name exists and currently points to some particular commit.  That said, though, every branch can have one *upstream* setting.

The upstream that you configure is taken as the merge argument if you run `git merge` with no arguments, or to use as the `<upstream>` argument for `git rebase` if you run that with no arguments, and so on.  Typically the upstream for `master` is `origin/master`.  You could set `sbr` (short branch) to have `origin/anotherLongNameBecauseTheyWantToReplaceUsWithRobots` as its upstream, and never have to type that again.

To set `origin/zorg` as the upstream for `evil`:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/zorg evil
```

and to remove the upstream:

```
git branch --unset-upstream evil
```

The upstream setting is simply a two-part field:

```
$ git config --get branch.master.remote
origin
$ git config --get branch.master.merge
master
```

This is how and why `master` has `origin/master` as its upstream.<sup>1</sup>  The upstream is also used automatically by `git status`, and is the default push target for `git push`, and is the result of applying `@{upstream}` to the branch name.  This is all built in to Git.  The catch is that you get only one upstream per branch.  If that's all you need, you are good.

You can add your own configuration items, e.g.:<sup>2</sup>

```
$ git config branch.master.zorblax giant-space-eel
```

but nothing in Git itself will use this.  Still, Git is a giant tool-set, not just a predigested solution that can never be used for anything outside the immediate imagination of its developers: you can write *your own* code that uses the `zorblax` setting, if you like.

---

<sup>1</sup>You can set a local branch as the upstream of another local branch.  Configuration-wise, this sets the `remote` part to `.`, which the rest of Git then ignores when necessary, e.g., for showing the `@{upstream}` setting symbolically.

There is also a hidden detail here having to do with branch name mapping, when `remote` is set to the name of a remote.  This is because the original value of the `merge` setting predates the invention of remotes.  Normally this makes no difference, though.

<sup>2</sup>[President Zorblax](http://smbc-comics.com/index.php?db=comics&id=486#comic).  Note date of comic, more than ten years ago.  I suspect the red-button text is newer, though....

Comment: You can just as easily track local branches.

Comment: @jthill: yes, I thought about mentioning that, but it seemed a bit off-target for his particular use.  I'll add it to footnote 1 though.