# Get remote name from local branch

Tags: git, bash

How to get the remote name from a local branch?

Note that I do not want the remote tracking branch name but just the remote name.

Consider this contrived example. How do I get `prefix/github`?

```
$ git status -b
## dev...prefix/github/rm/dev

$ git remote
github
prefix
prefix/github
```

So `prefix/github` is the remote and local branch `dev` is tracking remote branch `rm/dev`.

So far I know this way but it is not fullproof.

```
$ git rev-parse --abbrev-ref @{u} 2>/dev/null | cut -d'/' -f1
prefix
```

The `prefix/github` remote name is intentional. I can live with keeping my remote without forward slash (in which case the above would work) but wanted to know if I'm missing something.

fyi: I have a bash script where this eventually would be used.

Update:

See this comment for why this question is not a dupe:
[Get remote name from local branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43431277/get-remote-name-from-local-branch#comment73921535_43431277)

Comment: Are you trying to figure out where the remote branch which tracks a local branch lives?

Comment: Yes. So in above example I need to get `prefix/github` which is the remote name.

Comment: http://git-wt-commit.rubyforge.org/ directly, or replicate what it's doing.

Comment: What about `git branch -vv`?

Comment: What if you have multiple remotes? Which name would you like then?

Comment: @lasse-v-karlsen, It's not a dupe. Please read the question again / carefully. `git status -b` gives me the info that I require instead of `git branch -vv` which is superfluous.

Comment: @lasse-v-karlsen, If there are multiple remotes, then `git status -b` shows the last remote info for the branch.

Comment: It seems this works: `git config --get branch.dev.remote`.

Comment: You said "The `prefix/github` remote name is intentional", but you also have a remote named `prefix`. Don't do this: it is a trap. If you `git fetch` from both remotes `prefix` *and* `prefix/github`, Git's assumption that remote-tracking branch names are unique and determined solely by the remote name, breaks. It will work fine for a while, and then break. (Note that you can keep the name `prefix/github`, as long as you don't *also* use the name `prefix` by itself.)

Comment: Meanwhile, yes, `git config --get branch.dev.remote` is the correct answer ... and is in the answer that this is a not-quite-duplicate of. :-)

Comment: @torek, Yes, you are correct. I just made those up to make a point that simple grep is not sufficient. It will break fetch eventually. Good catch. The example still holds if I have `prefix-test/github` instead of `prefix/github`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works.

```
git config --get branch.dev.remote
```

The local git config file (`.git/config`) should have this `branch` section:

```
[branch "dev"]
    remote = prefix/github
    merge = refs/heads/dev
```

I'm honestly surprised it is this contrived.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by *contrived*, but it is this way for historical reasons. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/42033047/1256452 for a bit more. (I am sure I have written "more of more" about this elsewhere but could not find it quickly.)

Comment: @torek, Ah I see. I thought it would have been through `git branch` or `git remote` and not `git config` (which is not intuitive).

Comment: The user-oriented porcelain today tries to hide the fact that there are two parts to these things. Whether that's a good design decision is another question entirely. Meanwhile the plumbing code is chock full of historical oddities. :-)

Comment: Ah, I found the longer thing I wrote recently that describes this in more detail: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43318586/1256452

Comment: Does not work on a freshly created and unpushed Branch.

Answer (score -1):

The information you are looking for is stored in the `.git/config` file after you setup tracking for a branch. You should be able to extract it from there easily (e.g., `grep -B ... | grep ...` - please fill in the dots yourself after having a look in that file).

Note that there can be branches without remote tracking information stored explicitly there.