# how to push a subBranch to a branch?

Tags: git, github

`git checkout -b newBranch baseBranch`

I don't wanna `git push origin newBranch`

How can I push the `newBranch` as a childBranch of `baseBranch`

After that can I merge the `newBranch` directly to `master`?

Answer (score 4):

There is no notion of "child branch": a branch is simply a sequence of commits: Your `newBranch` simply starts from the current HEAD of `baseBranch`, but it is actually composed of all `baseBranch` commits, and of the new commits you are about to create.
See more at "[Find the parent branch of a Git branch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3161204/6309)".

You can push `newBranch` to GitHub without worrying about `baseBranch`.

```
git push -u origin newBranch
```

And you can merge that branch to any other branch you want.