# How to know base branch of any branch in beanstalk?

Tags: git

I've created the branch in beanstalk software but after long days I need to see from which base branch I've created that branch. How to know the base branch of any branch after creation in Beanstalk?

Comment: Possible similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161204/find-the-parent-branch-of-a-git-branch/3162929#3162929

Answer (score -1):

Git will only keep track of it's parent commit...not which branch it was originally based on, so there is no bullet-proof way to automate what you are seeking.

But, it should be fairly easy to see which branch is the base branch by visually inspecting your tree.

One convenient tool for this is `gitk`. Typing `gitk` into your console will bring up a GUI tool which shows you your current tree.

Starting at your HEAD commit, follow the parent commits until one of them has a branch label next to it and that will give you an idea of which branch you are based upon.

Note that this technique isn't bullet-proof as commits can have multiple branches pointing to them, so you will need to reach your conclusion manually.