# get name of a branch from which a (current) branch is created in git

Tags: git, git-branch

Lets say I created a branch called `feature1` from `develop` branch.

Also, I created a `issue123` branch from `feature1` branch.

Now I want to know that `feature1` is created from `develop` branch, and similarly `issue123` branch is created from `develop` branch.

How can I do that?

Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find the parent branch of a Git branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161204/find-the-parent-branch-of-a-git-branch)

Comment: @VicJordan tried this.. but did not get expected result.

Comment: what did you try? share your tried code

Comment: git show-branch -a \
| grep '\*' \
| grep -v `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` \
| head -n1 \
| sed 's/.*\[\(.*\)\].*/\1/' \
| sed 's/[\^~].*//'

Answer (score 0):

Not Exactly what you want, but some close solutions to it are ..

```
git show-branch
git show-branch --all
```

And,

```
git log --all --graph --decorate --oneline --simplify-by-decoration
```