# bad config line 34 in file /Users/yianwork/.gitconfig

Tags: git

How set the git alias to the git.
I have searched a git directive below from StackOverflow:

```
show-branch -a \
| grep '\*' \
| grep -v `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` \
| head -n1 \
| sed 's/.*\[\(.*\)\].*/\1/' \
| sed 's/[\^~].*//'
```

The URL is :

[Find the parent branch of a Git branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161204/find-the-parent-branch-of-a-git-branch)

Due to the directive is so long, I want to set an alias for it.

I looked the git document. I can't know how to set the complex directive as the alias.
[image]

Comment: Maybe use an actual alias, instead of a git one?

Comment: Would a simple `git config --global alias.alias "insert directive here"` work for you? If you run `git alias` now it will show every alias you set

Comment: @Matt95  I set the directive above into the alias.