# Find files that have changed of current branch without being able to compare to another branch

Tags: git

My CI environment only has the branch being pushed. Is it possible to see all files that have changed since the creation of the branch without comparing it to another branch?

I found multiple examples comparing branches, but nothing that worked when only one branch is available.

I'm trying to think outside the box, like number of commits with the branch name then get that many commits from the log like such where -n would be the number of commits:

```
git log --name-only --pretty=format: -n 5 | sed '/^$/d' | uniq
```

but I cannot find a way to get the correct number of commits

Comment: Branches do not have a creation point. They are merely a human-readable name for a single commit hash. (The set of branches that contain any given commit changes dynamically, and many commits are on many branches simultaneously.) To compare two commits, you need two commit hashes, which means you'll need another name or similar. See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/3161204/1256452

Comment: @torek that makes sense. I think I'll have to use a combination of git and bash to get what I want. Do you know of a way to get a list of all the commit hashes with their branch name? Even if I have to go to look through all commits I would be able to grep from there

Comment: `git rev-list <start-point>` lists all commits reachable from the given starting point, but that's not really very useful since so many commits are reachable from *every* starting point. Meanwhile if you want to translate each branch name to its corresponding hash ID—this is more useful, but still won't really get you what you want—see `git for-each-ref` for scripting, and remember that branch names are specifically those references in the `refs/heads/*` namespace. [continued]

Comment: [cont'd] I believe that what you are doing is going down the "all commits reachable from this branch but not any other branch" rathole, i.e., `git rev-list <branch> --not <all other branches>`. This method *works* ... for some limited use cases, but it's terribly fragile, because, well, see the linked question! Basically it breaks as soon as soon as someone starts getting clever with branch names. (The correct tool in a CI system is to mark your start-point, perhaps with a name in a name-space you make up specifically for your CI system.)

Answer (score 1):

## git log - include the initial commit

```
/mnt/c/git/ConsoleApp1 (master)>git log --name-only --oneline --pretty=format: | sort | uniq

ConsoleApp1/Class1.cs
ConsoleApp1/ConsoleApp1.csproj
ConsoleApp1/Program.cs
ConsoleApp1.sln
.gitignore
x.txt
z.txt
```

---

## git diff-tree Not including the first commit

1. Find the first commit e.g. `git rev-list` or `git log`
2. git diff-tree

   ```
   C:\git\ConsoleApp1>git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r 2f6e395..HEAD
   ConsoleApp1/Class1.cs
   x.txt
   z.txt
   ```

## git show - including first commit

1. Find the first commit e.g. `git rev-list` or `git log`
2. `git show` - *please note that git show is a porcelain command and it's not meant for scripting*

   ```
   C:\git\ConsoleApp1>git show --name-only --pretty="" -r 2f6e395..HEAD && git show --name-only --pretty="" -r 2f6e395
   z.txt
   x.txt
   ConsoleApp1/Class1.cs
   .gitignore
   ConsoleApp1.sln
   ConsoleApp1/ConsoleApp1.csproj
   ConsoleApp1/Program.cs
   ```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to come up with these examples. Each of them, unfortunately, is either showing me too much (the first example give me thousands of files) or too little (the last two didn't show me all files that have changed)

Comment: Yes, all these methods got to the root of the repo - I understood that's what you wanted