# How to know the name of the branch from where actual branch is created?

Tags: git

In git how to find the name of the branch from which my actual branch created?
Example:
I created my development branch(dev-feature) from integration branch(dev-int). How to trace the integration from feature branch?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find the parent branch of a Git branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161204/find-the-parent-branch-of-a-git-branch)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+find+parent+branch

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

You branch off from a *commit*, not from a branch. Branch is just a temporary tag that moves with commits while active.

Say there's a commit 0123456 where you have branch A and B. You make branch C. Which branch did you branch off of? The real answer is "neither" - you branched off from 0123456.

Also, branches don't remember where they started; the only thing you can do is trace the history back, and find where that history attached to the history of another branch. For example, to see where exactly `def-feature` history meets `dev-int` history,

```
git merge-base def-feature dev-int
```