# GIT: How can i check connection between branches?

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-bash, atlassian-sourcetree

Hi how can i chceck connection between branches in gitbash? I'm not sure that i did branches well. So I have Master -> dev -> feature and im not sure that feature is child of dev branch :)

Comment: Use a GUI Git client. [Fork](https://git-fork.com/), [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com) and [Git Extensions](http://gitextensions.github.io) are some good and free Git clients for Windows.

Comment: I use [gitk](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitk)

Comment: Ok but now where to find that. I use that i'm searching and can't find it

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3161204/2025395

Comment: Git branches are literally just pointers to a commit. There's no such thing as a "child branch". Can you explain what you want to know, maybe using a diagram?

Comment: The tools suggested by current answers likely will show you what you want to see, but it depends what exactly you're worried about having done "right" or not.  Because of how git's concept of a branch works, the only "connection" between branches is shared history, so beyond that there likely isn't anything to check - which is why any tool that shows the commit graph visually is likely to get you what you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can give this a try:

```
git log --graph --all --decorate --simplify-by-decoration
```

It will only show commits that are branch heads or tagged.

Answer (score 1):

In bash use https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show-branch

```
git show-branch --all
```

Or [gitk](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitk)

Git-Docu has also a page that lists GUI clients for different OS: https://git-scm.com/download/gui/windows