# How to determine your feature branch is created from develop or master branch in git

Tags: github

can anyone help me on

"How to determine your  feature branch is created from develop or master branch in github" ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to "[How to find the nearest parent of a Git branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3161204/6309)", which is not trivial.

But at least, a quick visual way would be

```
git log --decorate --oneline --graph --simplify-by-decoration
```