# How to get parent branch name?

Tags: git

I want to get the parent name of the current branch.

for example:
I have the following graph:

[image]

If I change my current branch to `A` (`git checkout A`) I want to get the name of the paranet branch (`master`)

And if I change my current branch to `B` (`git checkout B`) I want to get the name of the paranet branch (`A`)

I looked here:

[How to find the nearest parent of a Git branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161204/how-to-find-the-nearest-parent-of-a-git-branch)
but it didn't give me the results I want:

```
git log --graph --decorate
```

gives me:

```
git branch -a
  A
* B
  master
  remotes/origin/A
  remotes/origin/master

git log --graph --decorate
commit e3a6137ad7697faf74bfffb784249ffbd061f9e8 (HEAD -> B, origin/A, A)
...
 commit 8c4564d8800aebc0d374449f4040a7ae0dfabf9c (origin/master, master)
```

or:

```
 git checkout A

 git log --graph --decorate
 commit e3a6137ad7697faf74bfffb784249ffbd061f9e8 (HEAD -> A, origin/A, B)
 commit 8c4564d8800aebc0d374449f4040a7ae0dfabf9c (origin/master, master)
```

moreover there is no command `git parent`

so how can I get the name of the parent branch ?

Comment: I do not think there is a concept of a “parent” branch. A branch is a pointer to a commit.

Comment: Especially [the answer from VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3161347/10871900) mentioning `git branch --contains <commit>`