# Locate starting point of git branch

Tags: git

I'd like to be able to locate and ideally log only the commits for my branch (`experiment`). In other words, from `HEAD` of `experiment` to its starting point. It would be nice if I did not need to know the parent branch.

The reason why

```
git log HEAD..master
```

doesn't work for me, is because master is ahead of my branch:

```
A---B---F---G master
     \
      C---D---E experiment
```

For the same reason, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649356/how-do-i-run-git-log-to-see-changes-only-for-a-specific-branch) doesn't answer my question.

**EDIT:**
The reason why I was having trouble is I changed the history on `experiment` and it diverged from `master` so git logged all the commits in the branch, since it never found the point that the they shared history. Accepting [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68416671/4682839).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20015808/7976758, https://stackoverflow.com/a/24769534/7976758, https://stackoverflow.com/a/4649377/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-log%5D+branching+point

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show all commits in a git branch since original branching point from master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20015808/show-all-commits-in-a-git-branch-since-original-branching-point-from-master)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where did I branch from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898093/where-did-i-branch-from)

Comment: The starting point of branch `experiment` is commit `A`. That's the starting point for every branch. (Equivalently, we might as well just say that no branch ever has a starting point: the concept itself makes little sense.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you branched from `master` and are now on `experiment`, then stay on `experiment` and say

```
git log master..
```

Example on my machine. First, actual situation:

```
% git log --all --oneline --graph
* 5368511 (HEAD -> experiment) z
* 7f0990f y
* 5c7d1be x
| * d0d5a50 (master) c
| * 47a21c4 b
|/  
* 4dcb110 a
```

And then we say:

```
% git log --graph --oneline master..
* 5368511 (HEAD -> experiment) z
* 7f0990f y
* 5c7d1be x
```

But this does not meet the requirement that you don't want to have to work out what branch you branched from. It is actually quite hard to discover that, because Git has no concept of "branched from". We just did a big discussion of that here:

[git: diff between current branch and branch creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68207171/git-diff-between-current-branch-and-branch-creation)

You can see it's exactly the same issue: if you *know* what branch you "branched from", this is easy. If you don't, not so much.

Comment: The problem I'm experiencing is that it `git log` doesn't stop at the start point. It includes commit `A` if we're sticking with my example. And so I have no way of determining which commit is the actual start point.

Comment: Well it doesn't include commit A or B in my solution. To me, that's correct behavior. I can't imagine in what sense you'd want commit B to be part of the branch, since it didn't make any difference to anything; it already existed when you started the branch.

Comment: Added actual example from my machine.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. It was NOT working for me because it DID include commit `A`. We are on the same page with expected behavior. We do not want commit `A` or `B` to be part of the branch. Please see my [EDIT](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68415444/4682839) in the OP that explains why your solution was not working for me at first.

Comment: So basically the whole premise of the question was a misrepresentation?

Comment: Ok but then I don't see why my answer is accepted.

Comment: Because that is how you find the starting point, on a normal  branch. My finding renders this question a duplicate, because the other posts I and others linked answer it; but, that doesn't change the fact that your answer is correct. I also appreciate the added detail in response to finding the answer without knowledge of the parent branch.

Answer (score -2):

You are looking for the *merge base* of `master` and `experiment`. As far as Git is concerned, `A` is no less a part of `experiment` than it is of `master`.

```
$ git merge-base master experiment
B
```

Once you have that, you can use `git log` with `B^` (to ensure that `B` itself is included in the output, you want to start with `B`'s parent):

```
$ git log B^..HEAD
```