# Why PhpStorm doesn't show my branches graph right?

Tags: git, phpstorm

I have made two branches: `master` and `test`.
In `test` branch I have two commit in my test branch and I expect to  see two branches in my graph view, but I see one straight graph and seems it has one branch.

[image]

Also this is my git log:

[image]

Comment: It's because what you expect branches to be is different from what branches actually are. Your two branches are here, and the graph represents accurately what you have : two branches, one of which is two commits ahead of the other. Branches, like tags, are just pointers to *one* position on the commit tree. It's **not** a series of commits. Check the [doc](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell).

Comment: Not *precisely* a duplicate, but see [How to find the nearest parent of a Git branch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3161204/1256452)

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a trick question, or riddle, but: When is a branch not a branch?

Possible answers:

- When it's a twig.
- When it's a trunk.
- When it's in Git.

See also [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452)

The fact is that a Git commit graph is simply a Directed Acyclic Graph or [DAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph).  It's possible to draw this DAG in many ways:

```
*   (test)
|
*
 \
  *  (master)
  |
  *
  |
  *
```

or:

```
A--B--C   <-- master
       \
        D--E   <-- test
```

or, indeed, as what you've just seen: a straight line with two labels on it.  We could even draw it as:

```
         E   <-- test
        /
A      D
 \    /
  B--C   <-- master
```

if we like.  *All these drawings are the same*, in the same way that [a donut and a coffee cup are the same shape](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9NlqYr6-TpA).  (This explains why topologists' teeth are so bad.  Also, read the comments under the video.)

(Although it's probably too late, the TL;DR is: your expectation is wrong.)