# How to check the parent and child branch structure, find parent of a branch

Tags: git, branch, git-branch

I'm seeking a method or command in Git that allows me to determine the direct parent branch of the branch I'm currently working on. Is there a specific Git command or approach that provides this information?

Answer (score 4):

[To see the parent directly above your branch run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161204/how-to-find-the-nearest-parent-of-a-git-branch)

```bash
git show-branch \
| sed "s/].*//" \
| grep "\*" \
| grep -v "$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)" \
| head -n1 \
| sed "s/^.*\[//"
```

`git show-branch` works to see the structure as well. Every indent is a branch above.
[image]