# git show-branch -a complains that there are too many refs

Tags: git

I want to use the below on a windows 10 machine to know the nearest parent of a git branch.

But I am not able to run it, please help.

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

git show-branch -a \
| grep '\*' \
| grep -v `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` \
| head -n1 \
| sed 's/.*\[\(.*\)\].*/\1/' \
| sed 's/[\^~].*//'

# How it works:
# 1| Display a textual history of all commits.
# 2| Ancestors of the current commit are indicated
#    by a star. Filter out everything else.
# 3| Ignore all the commits in the current branch.
# 4| The first result will be the nearest ancestor branch.
#    Ignore the other results.
# 5| Branch names are displayed [in brackets]. Ignore 
#    everything outside the brackets, and the brackets.
# 6| Sometimes the branch name will include a ~2 or ^1 to
#    indicate how many commits are between the referenced
#    commit and the branch tip. We don't care. Ignore them.
```

I have taken the script form https://gist.github.com/joechrysler/6073741#file-who_is_my_mummy-sh

FYI, I have very limited Linux knowledge.

I don't want to use WSL or Cygwin

I have got the grep.exe and sed.exe and other exes from Linux utils.

Even If I run the below command in the windows command prompt, I get the below error

```
git show-branch -a | grep '\*'
```

**Error**:

> warning: ignoring origin/branchname; cannot handle more than 26 refs

**Edit**:

I saved the above command in a file parent.sh and When I run it in Git Bash, It gives the below error. Am I missing anything here?

[image]

Comment: @CherryDT Could you please guide me on how to run the above command? As I  am not from Linux background. How to run in Git Bash? I have added more info to the question, please refer

Comment: @Philippe what does that mean? Can I change it to bigger number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Linux or Windows, and not much to do with shells: you are running into a built in limit in the `git show-branch` command.  The `git show-branch` command has an internal maximum of 26 "refs" (branch names plus remote-tracking names).<sup>1</sup>  You have a large number of remote-tracking names—the names that start with `origin/`, such as `origin/63747`—and it's more than `git show-branch` can handle.

You could increase this limit by downloading the source for Git and building a new version of `git show-branch` that has a bigger limit in it, but that's a pretty big job even for an experienced C programmer (because it involves changing the way the bits work in show-branch, which gets its limit based on the number of flags used in internal commit objects; see [the `TODO` in `builtin/showbranch.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/bcd6bc478adc4951d57ec597c44b12ee74bc88fb/builtin/show-branch.c#L26-L34)).

You might just need a different (more capable) script.  Consider some of the other answers to this question: [How to find the nearest parent of a Git branch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3161204/1256452)

---

<sup>1</sup>Note that this limit used to be slightly larger (29, at the time some of the scripts in the above StackOverflow question were written).

Comment: I have already tried all the solutions mentioned in this answer and your answer is also telling me the limitations not the solution

Comment: @viveknuna Disliking the truth doesn't make the answer wrong.

Comment: There's one answer that, while it uses `git show-ref`, handles more than the limit. See in particular the [batch solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68673744/1256452).

Comment: @torek it’s not answering my question hence downvoted, nothing personal with you.

Comment: @matt above comment is for you. And please take it in the right spirit. If the answer works I would accept it.

Comment: @torek how to run the solution on a windows machine which is mentioned here, based on your link https://gist.github.com/rsitze/6a9d0ac280bca850e2471634a3f83204

Comment: You need to do some of your own homework and thinking here. It's clear that this particular adaptation has been modified to look specifically for branches whose name starts with `release/`. It also depends on the older version of Git where show-branch handled 29 branches at a time (note the MAX setting).