# How do I know if I'm running a nested shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

When using a *nix shell (usually bash), I often spawn a sub-shell with which I can take care of a small task (usually in another directory), then exit out of to resume the session of the parent shell.

Once in a while, I'll lose track of whether I'm running a nested shell, or in my top-level shell, and I'll accidentally spawn an additional sub-shell or exit out of the top-level shell by mistake.

Is there a simple way to determine whether I'm running in a nested shell?  Or am I going about my problem (by spawning sub-shells) in a completely wrong way?

Comment: I can tell when I'm in a login shell because I don't export PS1 and I only set it in .profile.  Thus, if I'm in a sub-shell, I get a '$' prompt (or some variant of a '$' prompt) instead of my normal prompt.

Comment: I don't understand the close votes either, hell, I made 95% of my rep via shell questions

Answer (score 90, accepted):

The `$SHLVL` variable tracks your shell nesting level:

```
$ echo $SHLVL
1
$ bash
$ echo $SHLVL
2
$ exit
$ echo $SHLVL
1
```

---

As an alternative to spawning sub-shells you could push and pop directories from the stack and stay in the same shell:

```
[root@localhost /old/dir]# pushd /new/dir
/new/dir /old/dir
[root@localhost /new/dir]# popd
/old/dir
[root@localhost /old/dir]#
```

Comment: Option to push/pop: `[root@/old/dir]# cd /new/dir` then  `[root@/new/dir]# cd -` will put you back in `[root@/old/dir]# `

Comment: Make it *always* print to your prompt by adding a printout of this variable to your `PS1` command prompt variable, as follows: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4511407/how-do-i-know-if-im-running-a-nested-shell/57665918#57665918

Answer (score 24):

Here is a simplified version of part of my prompt:

```
PS1='$(((SHLVL>1))&&echo $SHLVL)\$ '
```

If I'm not in a nested shell, it doesn't add anything extra, but it shows the depth if I'm in any level of nesting.

Comment: Extremely useful. Would like to see more of your .bashrc fu!

Comment: @Scalistro: OK, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A26428+bashrc), [here](http://serverfault.com/search?q=user%3A1293+bashrc), [here](http://superuser.com/search?q=user%3A310+bashrc) and [here](http://serverfault.com/search?q=user%3A382+bashrc).

Comment: @RobinA.Meade: Is the link intended to be an example of misleading information? Please point out in what way. In any case, I've updated my answer to use more precise wording.

Comment: Good answer! I like it to *always* print the `$SHLVL` value just above my prompt, so here's my spin on it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4511407/how-do-i-know-if-im-running-a-nested-shell/57665918#57665918

Answer (score 13):

Look at `$0`: if it starts with a minus `-`, you're in the login shell.

Comment: +1 because it does not make use of bashisms, but works generally.

Comment: Hmm, this works if I login on another virtual console, but not if I open a new `gnome-terminal`; there `$SHLVL` is 1 but the `$0` doesn't have a `-`. Also, in tmux, when I have `$SHLVL==2`, I get `$0` with a `-` in front. I'm confused.

Comment: This doesn't work after `exec zsh` (or whatever shell you use)

Answer (score 13):

`pstree -s $$` is quite useful to see your depth.

Comment: It's quite the information overload if you just want to see which level your current shell is in, though.

Answer (score 4):

The environment variable `$SHLVL` contains the shell "depth".

```
echo $SHLVL
```

The shell depth can also be determined using `pstree` (version 23 and above):

```
pstree -s $$ | grep sh- -o | wc -l
```

I've found the second way to be more robust than the first whose value was reset when using `sudo` or became unreliable with `env -i`.

None of them can correctly deal with `su`.

---

The information can be made available in your prompt:

```
PS1='\u@\h/${SHLVL} \w \$ '
PS1='\u@\h/$(pstree -s $$ | grep sh- -o | tail +2 | wc -l) \w \$ '
```

The `| tail +2` is there to remove one line from the `grep` output. Since we are using a pipeline inside a "`$(...)`" command substitution, the shell needs to invoke a sub-shell, so pstree report it and grep detects one more `sh-` level.

---

In debian-based distributions, `pstree` is part of the package `psmisc`. It might not be installed by default on non-desktop distributions.

Answer (score 3):

As [@John Kugelman says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4511483/4561887), `echo $SHLVL` will tell you the bash shell depth.
And as [@Dennis Williamson shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4512898/4561887), you can edit your prompt via the `PS1` variable to get it to print this value.

I prefer that it *always* prints the shell depth value, so here's what I've done: edit your `~/.bashrc` file:

```bash
gedit ~/.bashrc
```

and add the following line to the end:

```bash
export PS1='\$SHLVL'":$SHLVL\n$PS1"
```

Now you will *always* see a printout of your current bash level just above your prompt. Ex: here you can see I am at a bash level (depth) of 2, as indicated by the `$SHLVL:2`:

> ```bash
> $SHLVL:2  
> 7510-gabriels ~ $
> ```

Now, watch the prompt as I go down into some bash levels via the `bash` command, then come back up via `exit`. Here you see my commands and prompt (response), starting at level 2 and going down to 5, then coming back up to level 2:

```bash
$SHLVL:2 
7510-gabriels ~ $ bash
$SHLVL:3 
7510-gabriels ~ $ bash
$SHLVL:4 
7510-gabriels ~ $ bash
$SHLVL:5 
7510-gabriels ~ $ exit
exit
$SHLVL:4 
7510-gabriels ~ $ exit
exit
$SHLVL:3 
7510-gabriels ~ $ exit
exit
$SHLVL:2 
7510-gabriels ~ $
```

### Bonus: always show in your terminal your current `git branch` you are on too!

Make your prompt also show you your **git branch you are working on** by using the following in your "~/.bashrc" file instead:

```bash
git_show_branch() {
    __gsb_BRANCH=$(git symbolic-ref -q --short HEAD 2>/dev/null)
    if [ -n "$__gsb_BRANCH" ]; then
        echo "$__gsb_BRANCH"
    fi
}
export PS1="\e[7m\$(git_show_branch)\e[m\n\h \w $ "
export PS1='\$SHLVL'":$SHLVL $PS1"
```

Source: I have no idea where `git_show_branch()` originally comes from, but I got it from Jason McMullan on 5 Apr. 2018. I then added the `$SHLVL` part shown above just last week.

Sample output:

> ```bash
> $SHLVL:2 master  
> 7510-gabriels ~/GS/dev/temp $
> ```

And here's a screenshot showing it in all its glory. Notice the git branch name, `master`, *highlighted in white*!

[image]

### My latest `PS1` prompt

I've improved my `PS1` prompt again and put it in my [eRCaGuy_dotfiles](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles) repo. It is inside my [`~/.bash_aliases`](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/blob/master/home/.bash_aliases) file, which is sourced by my [`~/.bashrc`](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/blob/master/home/.bashrc) file. Search my [`~/.bash_aliases`](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/blob/master/home/.bash_aliases) file for both my `PS1` entries and the `gs_git_show_branch_and_hash` function used by them.

Here's a sample output of the new terminal prompt. Notice how it shows the shell level as `1`, and it shows the branch name of the currently-checked-out branch (`master` in this case), as well as its short git hash (`bac27c7` in this case), whenever I'm inside a local git repo!:

[image]

This is really helpful to help me ensure I'm always performing my `git` operations on the correct branch, and to automatically see whenever I `cd` into a Git repository.

### Cross-referenced:

- [Output of git branch in tree like fashion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421011/output-of-git-branch-in-tree-like-fashion/54897514#54897514)

Answer (score 0):

`ptree $$` will also show you how many levels deep you are

Comment: `command not found` :/

Answer (score -1):

If you running inside sub-shell following code will yield 2:

```
ps | fgrep bash | wc -l
```

Otherwise, it will yield 1.

**EDIT** Ok, it's not so robust approach as was pointed out in comments :)
Another thing to try is

```
ps -ef | awk '{print $2, " ", $8;}' | fgrep $PPID
```

will yield 'bash' if you in sub-shell.

Comment: It depends how deep you are - if you've created a sub-shell within a sub-shell, it'll be 3.

Comment: you might want to add `| grep -v grep` before `wc` -- and hope that you don't have any other shells open under your id.

Comment: @Seidr Just don't go down 4 sub-shells, it's pure code fragments down there and you may never come back if your program crashes while you're that deep.

Comment: @tvan it's cleaner to use `grep [b]ash` or better yet just use `pgrep` and remove the call to `ps` altogether