# What do you understand by "nested Shell"?

Tags: shell, linux-kernel, operating-system, kernel

I'm new with SHELL SCRIPTING, I just started knowing about nested shell . But I'm yet not aware of its exact meaning ( what's happening behind the scene when we say NESTED SHELL ) . Like , when someone says nested shell is " shell inside shell " then i wanna ask how a TERMINAL emulator window is gonna communicate with the inner shell ? and further how inner shell is gonna get the output by communicating to whom?
[[How do I know if I'm running a nested shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4511407/how-do-i-know-if-im-running-a-nested-shell][1])

Above link just says about the way to know if i'm using nested shell and if YES then how deep it is . But it is not i'm asking . I'm asking about the real meaning .

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you're asking about here - are you wondering about how the kernel creates child processes? A "nested shell" is just a shell whose parent is a shell.

Comment: @TomFenech see my edited explaination . hope you understand this time?

Comment: @AbhishekKumar: I recommend you reading the K&P Unix book to get these basics cleared out. https://www.amazon.com/Unix-Programming-Environment-Prentice-Hall-Software/dp/013937681X