# How can I know what was the latest changes made to a branch?

Tags: git

git version 1.7.4.4

I am working on a new project from my development team.

So I have just cloned the project. The project has 5 branches.

I need to know what branch was the latest changes made to. So I can start working on that branch, as that would have the latest changes.

I have looked at the log. However, but that doesn't tell me that branches those commits where made to.

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: This is not your answer: just if you are using linux/unix, I suggest you to see [gitg](http://trac.novowork.com/gitg/), it can help you much times.

Comment: I am using Linux. Any other OS is just a waste of time. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `git log --decorate` would add tags and branches to each line.

```
--decorate[=short|full|no]
```

> Print out the ref names of any commits that are shown.
>   If `short` is specified, the ref name prefixes `refs/heads/`, `refs/tags/` and `refs/remotes/` will not be printed.
>   If `full` is specified, the full ref name (including prefix) will be printed.
>   The default option is `short`.

Comment: While this is the way to solve your problem, I seriously think you should rely on communicating with your team (where do we do work, which branch is pushed out to production etc.) rather than just pick the most forward branch and start working there. This is indicative of a deeper problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `git for-each-ref` to get a list of branches ordered by the date of the last commit on those branches, for instance:

```
git fetch origin # Update all your remote tracking branches from origin

git for-each-ref --sort=committerdate refs/remotes/origin/
```

The branches listed at the end have the most recent commits at their tip.  (For a script that produces the relevant dates as well as the branch name you could [look here](http://longair.net/blog/2011/03/14/git-too-many-topic-branches/).)

Comment: Much more precise way to get the right branch. +1. Should be the official answer if you ask me.