# Color in git-log

Tags: git, git-log

When you run `git log --decorate --pretty=oneline` the output will have entries like `(HEAD, refs/published/master, master)` with coloration.

I also have the following in my gitconfig:

```
[color "branch"]
    current = yellow reverse
    local = yellow
    remote = green
```

How do you replicate those colors when doing a custom format like the following?

```
git log --decorate --stat --graph --pretty=format:"%d %Cgreen%h%Creset (%ar - %Cred%an%Creset), %s%n"
```

Answer (score 101, accepted):

As of git 1.8.3 (May 24, 2013), you can use `%C(auto)` to decorate `%d` in the format string of `git log`.

From the [release notes](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.3.txt):

```
 * "git log --format" specifier learned %C(auto) token that tells Git
   to use color when interpolating %d (decoration), %h (short commit
   object name), etc. for terminal output.)
```

Answer (score 64):

The `git log --decorate` will put by default:

- the HEAD in cyan
- the remote branches in red
- the tag in green

and can be changed through  **`color.decorate`** config.

But the [`git log --format`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_pretty_formats) don't offer a way to display specifically the `HEAD` *or* remotes *or* branch: all three are displayed through `%d`, with one color possible.

---

Update May 2013, as [mentioned below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16844346/6309) by [Elad Shahar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2263682/elad-shahar) (upvoted), git 1.8.3 offers one more option:

> `git log –format` now sports a `%C(auto)` token that tells Git to use color when resolving `%d` (decoration), `%h` (short commit object name), etc. for terminal output.

This [Atlassian blog post](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/05/highlights-git-1-8-3/) comments that this feature is part of several others focused on format (`git rebase`, `git count-objects`) and colors (`git branch -vv`)

This comes in addition of the previous [`auto,reset` of 1.8.2](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/03/highlights-new-git-1-8-2/), which automatically disables colors when the output is not used for a terminal1

```
%C(auto,blue)Hello%C(auto,reset)
```

---

Note: git 2.4+ (Q2 2015) will do a better job of resetting color around branch names.
See [commit 5ee8758](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5ee875852e3cb41c21c2e89a636fc1e40c4012b1) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster):

> ### `log --decorate`: do not leak "commit" color into the next item
>
> In "`git log --decorate`", you would see the commit header like this:

```
commit ... (HEAD, jc/decorate-leaky-separator-color)
```

> where "`commit ... (`" is painted in `color.diff.commit`, "`HEAD`" in `color.decorate.head`, "`,` " in `color.diff.commit`, the branch name in
>   `color.decorate.branch` and then closing "`)`" in `color.diff.commit`.
>
> If you wanted to paint the HEAD and local branch name in the same color as the body text (perhaps because cyan and green are too faint on a black-on-white terminal to be readable), you would not want to have to say

```
[color "decorate"]
    head = black
    branch = black
```

> because that you would not be able to reuse same configuration on a white-on-black terminal.  You would naively expect

```
[color "decorate"]
    head = normal
branch = normal
```

> to work, but unfortunately it does not.
>   It paints the string "`HEAD`" and the branch name in the same color as the opening parenthesis or comma between the decoration elements.
>   This is because the code forgets to reset the color after printing the "prefix" in its own color.

---

Note that git 2.5 (Q2 2015) fixes a bug:

See [commit 429ad20](https://github.com/git/git/commit/429ad204136b2de1cfd2e7f7f5b20df211996c9f) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster), 13 May 2015.
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit fd70780](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fd707807f012438ab58ce6bd819ea38feca781a7), 22 May 2015)</sup>

> ### `log`: do not shorten decoration names too early
>
> The "`log --decorate`" enhancement in Git 2.4 that shows the commit at the tip of the current branch e.g. "`HEAD -> master`", did not work with --decorate=full.

---

Git 2.9.x+ (Q3 2016) will fix another bug and [honor `color=auto` for `%C(auto)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37933969/6309)

---

Git 2.10.2 (Oct. 2016) fixes other bugs with [commit 82b83da](https://github.com/git/git/commit/82b83da8d30fb8d1f04f7dd7ac769ceb6ab431c3) (29 Sep 2016), and [commit c99ad27](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c99ad274b196bc97f22c1c39178784668cb4623d) (17 Sep 2016) by [René Scharfe (``)](https://github.com/).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 76796d4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/76796d424a21b1def8752c686708253a45721381), 28 Oct 2016)</sup>

> ### `pretty`: avoid adding reset for `%C(auto)` if output is empty
>
> We emit an escape sequence for resetting color and attribute for `%C(auto)` to make sure automatic coloring is displayed as intended.
>   **Stop doing that if the output strbuf is empty**, i.e. when `%C(auto)` appears at the start of the format string, because then there is no need for a reset and we save a few bytes in the output.
>
> ### `pretty`: let `%C(auto)` reset all attributes
>
> Reset colors *and attributes* upon `%C(auto)` to enable full automatic
>   control over them; **otherwise attributes like bold or reverse could
>   still be in effect from previous `%C` placeholders**.

Comment: is there no way to use --decorate and --pretty="...stuff"?

Comment: @NorthlsUp: `--decorate` seems to have its own implementation and configuration, while `--pretty` offers the same information through `%d` as one block, meaning you cannot have the same fine-grained level of color configuration with `--pretty` than you have with `--decorate`.

Comment: The only difference I see when I add "--decorate" after "git log" is the repos begin with either "refs/heads/..." or "refs/remotes...". The colors show up either way. Any idea what would cause this? The reason I ask is my .gitconfig does not show any color properties. I'm wondering where i can find my "color.decorate" property. I don't see it in my .gitconfig file.

Comment: @JWoodchuck Try `git config --show-origin -l`: you will see *all* your configs. You can then grep for "color".

Comment: Yep, nothing shows up when i grep for color, which makes where the settings are showing up so mysterious.

Comment: @JWoodchuck That might be because color.ui is set to true or auto since Git 1.8.4: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-colorui

Comment: Sounds plausible, considering that's apparently from a long time ago and I'm on 2.16.2. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Parenthesize them:

> `%C(...): color specification, as described in color.branch.* config option`

So `%C(yellow reverse)` would work.

Comment: not quite, `%d` is all branches so it could look like `(HEAD, master)`, in this case head should be blue and master should be green (I believe those are the default colors).  where `%C(yellow)%d%Creset` would make it all the same color.

Comment: Oh, coloring the individual decorations. I think it’s impossible. The code to render log entries is essentially implemented twice.

Comment: Too bad this isn't possible... I would love to do `git log --decorate --oneline --date=...`

Answer (score 8):

The config option `log.decorate` can enable/disable default decorations in logs.

```
git config --global log.decorate full
```

Once that is done you can use `color.decorate.*` to play with the colors

Comment: `log.decorate=full` causes the ref names to be printed with their prefixes (`refs/heads/`, etc.); I find `log.decorate=short` more useful.

Comment: Very useful setting, although I also prefer `short` rather than `full`

Answer (score 5):

Some may want to use this : `%C(colorname)`
This doesn't need to change the color config.

*Example : Coloring the author name in yellow*

```
--pretty=format:"%C(yellow)%an%Creset"
```

Regular ANSI colors should work https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code

- black
- red
- green
- yellow
- blue
- magenta
- cyan
- white

Comment: can we use alternative colors like gray?