# A git log history graph with one line per commit, in color, with dates

Tags: git, git-log

I need to have format like:

```
git log --decorate --graph --oneline --date-order
```

but I need it also:

1. to contain date (short)
2. to have the same colors

I tried:

```
git log --decorate --graph --oneline --date-order \
--date=short --pretty=format:"%h %ad %s"
```

but it's harder to read (no colors) and does not include branches/tags

---

The closest simple solution is(thanks [VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc)):

```
git log --graph --pretty=format:'%C(yellow)%h%Creset \
-%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' \
--abbrev-commit --date=short
```

Comment: You can use VonC's example but for refspec use %C(auto)%d to get the references automatically colored

Comment: appending an answer into one's question is confusing. Better to use stack overflow correctly by accepting the correct answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can try:

```
alias.lgb=log --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit --date=short --branches
```

It has different color, but you can change them easily.

for instance:

```
git log --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h -%d %s (%cr) <%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit --date=short --branches
```

Comment: Note: Use `%ad` instead of `%an` to get back your short dates.

Comment: that looks pretty nice, except that branches do not have different color depending on if they are local or remote and also tags have the same color as branches. it's very useful to distinguish these. Also HEAD is light blue - shows you where you are at the moment

Comment: @NickSoft: on the color issue for tag and branches, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889878/color-in-git-log/5892582#5892582

Comment: well they say it's impossible, which doesn't quite work for me. isn't there any way to add date when using --oneline and not custom format?

Comment: @NickSoft: it doesn't seem possible, not to my knowledge at least.

Comment: +1 For being pretty close to my requirements and for the simplicity of the solution.

Comment: +1, Love it. I'm collecting useful formats in my `[pretty]` config section, and this one's my default :)

Answer (score 6):

Well, "impossible" means that there is no easy way and I'll have to do it myself. I worried too much that I always make things the hard way, when there is actually easier way.

Here is a bash+php script. I tried to make it with sed, but I failed.

I named this script git-gd and put it in a bin directory that's in path `/usr/local/bin/` and I use it with git: `git gd` or `git gd <options>`

```
#!/bin/bash

GIT="/usr/local/bin/git"
PHP="/bin/php"
GIT_DATES="$GIT log --date=short --abbrev-commit --pretty=format:%C(yellow)%h_%C(green)[%ad]%Creset --branches --color=always $*"
#if you have have alias g
GIT_GRAPH="$GIT g --color=always"
#or
#GIT_GRAPH="$GIT log --decorate --graph --oneline --date-order --color=always"
PHP_SCRIPT='
  $exps = explode("\n", $_SERVER["argv"][1]);
  $lines = file("php://stdin");
  $s = array();
  $r=$s;
  foreach($exps as $exp){
   $exp = trim($exp);
   list($commit,)=explode("_", $exp);
   $s[] = $commit;
   $r[] = str_replace("_", " ", $exp);
  }
  foreach($lines as $line){
    $line = str_replace($s, $r, $line);
    echo $line ;
  }
  '

DATES=`$GIT_DATES`
$GIT_GRAPH $* |$PHP -r "$PHP_SCRIPT" -- "$DATES"
```

I'll wait a bit for simpler solution and I'll accept my own answer

Answer (score 5):

In non-ancient versions of git you can configure `git log` to enable decorations thusly:

```
git config --global log.decorate full
```

Comment: `log.decorate=full` causes the ref names to be printed with their prefixes (`refs/heads/`, etc.); I find `log.decorate=short` more useful.

Answer (score 2):

In addition in your git config you can add two lines like this:

```
[format]
  pretty = %Cblue%h%Creset %Cgreen[%ar]%Creset (%an) %s
```

This just means you can type git log and it will always be formatted.

Answer (score 1):

To log your commits neatly and formatted use

```
git log --pretty=format:"%h - %an, %ar : %s"
```

- see commits on branch