# git log not showing updated records

Tags: git

I have two branches "master" and "experiment", both locally and at a remote repo. They are both synced, i.e. the HEAD is the same commit, both locally and at remote.

I make a commit to "master" locally and then push it to remote "master".

I then decide that I'd like to have "experiment" at the current status as "master"(sync/merge with master, yet maintain it as a separate branch).

So locally I move to the "experiment" branch and do :-
    git fetch origin mainline

However, after doing the fetch, doing a "git log" in "experiment" does now show the new commits in them. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should show all the commit from the various branches:

```
git log --all --branches
```

(you can see a [more compact `git log` here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7430132/6309))

A git fetch alone doesn't update the commit of your local branch, only of the one in the remote namespace (ie, the branch `origin/mainline`).
To update your local '`experiment`' branch with a remote one you have fetch, add:

```
git checkout experiment
git merge origin/mainline
```

Then a simple `git log` will show you a new commit.

Answer (score 1):

If you not found all record you can find all logs in git **rootDir>.git>logs>HEAD** file.