# How to emulate git log --decorate's different colors per branch-type

Tags: git, git-config

In making my favorite git log view I've created this alias:

`graph = log --pretty=format:'%Cgreen%ad%Creset %C(yellow)%h%Creset%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %C(cyan)[%an]%Creset %Cgreen(%ar)%Creset' --date=short --graph`

This creates an output like:

[image: Git log result with own coloring]

What I'm missing here is the different coloring of branch types like in `log --oneline --decorate --graph`.

[image: Git log result with --decorate(=short)]

The --decorate (which uses =short by default) gives the different recognized branches a different color. The branch types `(HEAD, origin/master, origin/HEAD, master)` are colored cyan, red, red, green. Mine however are uncolored; colored only with the yellow of the whole branches part.

**Is there a way to give different colors to the different *kind* of branches with an own alias?**

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Per https://stackoverflow.com/a/16844346/55948

> As of git 1.8.3 (May 24, 2013), you can use `%C(auto)` to decorate
>   `%d` in the format string of `git log`.
>
> From the [release
>   notes](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.3.txt):
>
> ```
>  * "git log --format" specifier learned %C(auto) token that tells Git
>    to use color when interpolating %d (decoration), %h (short commit
>    object name), etc. for terminal output.)
> ```

Comment: Awesome!!! Looked for this for a couple hours, thanks!!! For google, adding some keywords: %d, ref names, --oneline

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm stuck with version 1.7.12.4 :( so %d and %C(auto) won't work. While the %ad %an %h ... etc colors can be defined individually, I'm having troubles with the color for the branches names. Any ideas where the string format for *oneline* can be found?

Comment: This is just what I was looking for.  Nearly did it the hard way, but you just saved me a bunch of effort! :-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is possible. Looking through the [git-log(1)](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) man page, the only relevant format for `--pretty` seems to be `%d`, which gives you all the ref names. Since there aren't any options which distinguish the type of reference, you can't give each type a different color.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889878/color-in-git-log).

Comment: This answer is no longer true. As of git 1.8.3 (May 24, 2013), you can use %C(auto) to decorate %d in the format string of git log.