# git log --decorate colors all the same

Tags: git, colors

I've apt-get installed git version 1.7.0.4 on a fresh install of Ubuntu 10.04 on my new SSD. Everything works fine, except all log decorations - tags, local branches, remote branches, HEAD - are all always orange in a default bash terminal, as are the surrounding  parentheses, all matching the SHA-1 hash value coloring. Nothing I do will change them. If I remove `ui = auto` from `[color]` in ~/.gitconfig then it all goes monochrome, but outside that, I can't get the default remote=red, local=green, HEAD=cyan, tag=yellow coloring that I had on the old Ubuntu 10.04 install I've just moved from.

There are no other color things in `~/.gitconfig` (it's very default/vanilla, and even stripping it all out doesn't fix it), and there's nothing related to colors in `myrepo/.git/config`. This happens in all repos.

Do I have a bad install? Is it a terminal issue? I've fiddled with everything related to fonts, colors, backgrounds, etc, in the terminal profile properties to no avail. I've tried everything I can find related to colors online and on stackoverflow... no luck. Colors do seem to work in diffs, i.e. this does change the meta info for each file in a diff:

```
[color "diff"]
    meta = magenta
```

Comment: What shell and what terminal are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 10.04 defaults (i.e. Applications->Accessories->Terminal), which I believe is bash and gnome-terminal. Those are what get listed in System->Administration->System Monitor.

Comment: Here's an example of `git log --decorate` output: http://i.imgur.com/4ZHAF.png - origin/* should be red, master should be green, thisisatag is a tag and should be yellow, and HEAD should be cyan. It looks like this for every variation of git log that I've tried (i.e. --oneline, --graph, any combination of flags).

Comment: It's also all orange for me too. Why do you say it should be those colors?

Comment: They were there for me previously with the same setup: Ubuntu 10.04; unsure of the git version then, but I thought I did the same thing, i.e. `sudo apt-get install git-core` on my old install, but perhaps not. It also does this by default on my install on Windows 7 at work - same colors as mentioned (likely a newer version from a binary from the site). I've also seen many people talk about these colors as defaults, as seen [in this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5892582/955926). Also, I just downloaded and built 1.8.0.1 from http://git-scm.com/ and it had these default colors.

Comment: [Here's an example](https://raw.github.com/wiki/Stanford-Online/class2go/git-log-oneline-example.png) of what I expect, though in looking for that example I uncovered far more examples of same coloration. Maybe this was an addition post 1.7.0.4? Maybe I did pull it down from the site before, and didn't use apt-get. This is very confusing.

Comment: Could be that it's a new git thing and that they haven't put it up in the 10.04 repositories.

Comment: I pathed back in to the old disk and ran `git --version` from `/usr/bin`. It was also 1.7.0.4. My only guess left was that I had a newer version there, but it doesn't seem so. It always colored that way, from the moment I set `color = auto` the first day or so. Some sort of repo regression, perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

Just found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10998792/how-to-color-the-git-console-in-ubuntu#answer-13075208), the one-liner worked for me. And, I'm on Ubuntu 12.04.

```
git config --global color.ui auto
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work for me on Ubuntu 10.04, even if I build from source. I have ui set to auto, and that does give me colors, but it doesn't give me individual colors for local vs. remote branches, tags, and HEAD. I got a new laptop recently, and installing git through the 12.10 repo has it working fine on there. I still don't know if this is a version change issue, compile flag, setting, or something else entirely.