# Don't colorize the refs with git log --pretty when --no-color is specified

Tags: git, posh-git

I'm working with Git, using Windows 7, PowerShell, and Posh-Git.  I have the following alias setup:

```
ls = log --pretty=tformat:"%C(yellow)%h\\ %C(green)[%ad]%C(cyan)\\ <%cn>\\ %C(reset)%s%C(auto)%d"
```

The problem was that when I pipe the output to clip.exe to copy it to the clipboard, it also copies some characters for the colors.  A little reading and I found you could add "auto," so that it would use the default colors if the `--no-color` option is specified.  So now I have:

```
ls = log --pretty=tformat:"%C(auto,yellow)%h\\ %C(auto,green)[%ad]%C(auto,cyan)\\ <%cn>\\ %C(auto,reset)%s%C(auto)%d"
```

The problem I now have is the last bit of the output showing the refs. I have the color set to auto so that git will apply the default colors for branches and tags, but can't figure out how to get it to respect the `--no-color` option.  If I set it to %C(auto) the colors show all the time.  I tried %C(auto,auto) and that works with `--no-color`, but without it git complains:

```
error: invalid color value: auto
fatal: unable to parse --pretty format
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> can't figure out how to get it to respect the `--no-color` option.
>   If I set it to `%C(auto)`, the colors show all the time.

This will be fixed in git 2.9.x+ (Q3 2016)

See [commit b15a3e0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b15a3e005af07843116c73205742adfbab3d2e82) (27 May 2016) by [Edward Thomson (`ethomson`)](https://github.com/ethomson).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 1b3d14c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1b3d14c1c89d8ad61be97a1f2d2606a07b25872b), 20 Jun 2016)</sup>

> ### [`format_commit_message`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/ab7797dbe95fff38d9265869ea367020046db118/pretty.c#L1469): honor `color=auto` for `%C(auto)`
>
> [`git-log(1)`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) documents that when specifying the `%C(auto)` format
>   placeholder will "turn on auto coloring on the next `%placeholders` until the color is switched again."
>
> However, when `%C(auto)` is used, the present implementation will turn
>   colors on unconditionally (even if the color configuration is turned off
>   for the current context - for example, `--no-color` was specified or the
>   color is `auto` and the output is not a tty).
>
> Update [`format_commit_one`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/ab7797dbe95fff38d9265869ea367020046db118/pretty.c#L1052) to examine the current context when a format
>   string of `%C(auto)` is specified, which ensures that we will not
>   unconditionally write colors.
>   This brings that behavior in line with the behavior of `%C(auto,<colorname>)`, and allows the user the ability to specify that color should be displayed only when the output is a
>   tty.

This is what you see with git-for-windows 2.9.0

[image: no-color does not work]

But with a more recent 2.9.x+ git version, `--no-color` does work:

[image: no-color does work]

Comment: I'm on git 2.9.2 now and can verify this was fixed.  Thanks.

Comment: And thank you to  Edward Thomson who made the patch!