# How to reproduce the format of git log --oneline --decorate?

Tags: git, git-log

Where is the format of git log --oneline --decorate defined?

Using git Iog  --format=format:'my format', I cannot reproduce the colours of the branches, tags and HEAD as shown by git log --oneline --decorate.

```
 git log --oneline --decorate
```

shows HEAD in light blue, the branch names in green and the punctuations (,,) in brown.

The closest I have come to getting what I want is:

```
git log --graph --abbrev-commit --decorate --date=short --format=format:'%C(bold blue)%h%C(reset) %C(bold green)%ad%C(reset)%d %C(white)%s%C(reset)' -20
```

with the only difference being that the branches/HEAD/tags are not coloured like with the previous command.

Answer (score 9):

It does not appear to be possible with git version < 1.8.3.

Since git 1.8.3, one could use the colour %C(auto) token:

```
   git log --graph --decorate --date=short --format='%C(bold blue)%h%C %C(bold green)%ad %C(auto)%d  %C(white)%s%C(reset)' -10
```

The key element being:

```
%C(auto)%d ...  %C(reset)
```

See also:

[Color in git-log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889878/color-in-git-log)
[Git pretty format colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15458237/git-pretty-format-colors)

Comment: Instead of `%d` you may want to use `%D` for some use cases but `%d` does match the `--oneline --decorate` rendering. Also note that `%Creset` does also work but `%Cauto` does not work and one must use `%C(auto)` for nice colors. Also, you may often want `tformat` instead of `format`.

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen, you are correct about `tformat`. There is a shorthand `--format=xxx` for `--format=tformat:xxx`, but I do not really know when it was introduced, and the answer as it stands is backward-compatible to 1.8.3, so I'm reluctant to edit it. `--abbrev-commit` seems superfluous, even probably for 1.8.3, however, because `%h` already stands for the abbreviated form. I'll leave both point to augustin to decide. The third one is that `%C(reset)` is excessive right before the next `%C…`. It's a very helpful answer, even in its current form.

Comment: @kkm I edited the answer as per your suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR** - I don't think it's possible for you to get the exact format that `git log --oneline` provides because the `--format` option doesn't allow any conditional statements, while `git-log` is using a function to generate that string on a per commit message.

The closest I got with the colors is this:

```
git log --format=format:'%C(auto)%h%C(reset) %C(auto)%s%C(reset)'
```

Looks like this on my machine:

[image: terminal-screenshot]

---

**Long version:**

The most documentation you can read on git-log is here: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log

I delved into the source (available on github [here](https://github.com/git/git)) to see what exactly git does for the `--oneline` option, here's what I found:

- The trail starts here in [`revision.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/35f6318d44379452d8d33e880d8df0267b4a0cd0/revision.c#L1901), where the command line options are parsed
- The option is then parsed in [`pretty.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/35f6318d44379452d8d33e880d8df0267b4a0cd0/pretty.c#L152) to match `CMIT_FMT_ONELINE` of the `cmit_fmt` enum (defined in [`commit.h`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/35f6318d44379452d8d33e880d8df0267b4a0cd0/commit.h#L125))
- Finally, the actual printing happens over in `pretty.c` at [`pp_commit_easy`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/35f6318d44379452d8d33e880d8df0267b4a0cd0/pretty.c#L1831).
- This is where it gets tricky and complicated. You can see references to `CMIT_FMT_ONELINE` in a handful of places in `pretty.c`. I believe that only [`pp_title_line`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/35f6318d44379452d8d33e880d8df0267b4a0cd0/pretty.c#L1575) is executed for each commit when the `--oneline` option is specified. You can see that there's a bunch of conditional formatting going on as the string buffer is constructed.

So yeah, I don't think there's a way to replicate the actual format with the tags and `(HEAD -> master)` meta information. You can probably write a shell script that does the same, but its performance may not match up to that of git's.

Answer (score 1):

This should now (7 years later) be possible with Git 2.43 (Q4 2023), "[`git log --format`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/86b56ff267962ab91aa368b10d6df10b1e9e291e/Documentation/pretty-options.txt#L2)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---formatltformatgt))</sup> has been taught the `%(decorate)` placeholder.

See [commit 1e63b34](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1e63b34a449afd650b02ab19501e8ccf0c15816e), [commit f1f8a25](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f1f8a258567268974b9bbd012c33ad219a31aa0e), [commit a58dd83](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a58dd835e9536cf9e7adcd404d008a44d29af804), [commit dcb347f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dcb347f83780b67ba586fda67a5c494b31354eae), [commit b87a9a2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b87a9a2c1ef8c39d4fc3d1e28ebb79563d4804be), [commit a3883a6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a3883a6532163f0a53a7b202f32bf8fe565af056), [commit 31a922f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/31a922f8383ea75b5757d2f9d0615c85b2083b5a) (20 Aug 2023) by [Andy Koppe (`akoppecodek`)](https://github.com/akoppecodek).
See [commit 014aa1d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/014aa1d1aae2548c644959bdba766a66b6a7f5cb) (20 Aug 2023) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 86b56ff](https://github.com/git/git/commit/86b56ff267962ab91aa368b10d6df10b1e9e291e), 14 Sep 2023)</sup>

> ### [`pretty`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a58dd835e9536cf9e7adcd404d008a44d29af804): add `%(decorate[:<options>])` format
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Andy Koppe</sup>

> Add `%(decorate[:<options>])` format that lists ref names similarly to the `%d` format, but which allows the otherwise fixed prefix, suffix and separator strings to be customized.
> Omitted options default to the strings used in `%d`.
>
> Rename `expand_separator()` function used to expand `%x` literal formatting codes to `expand_string_arg()`, as it is now used on strings other than separators.
>
> Examples:
>
> - `%(decorate)` is equivalent to `%d`.
> - `%(decorate:prefix=,suffix=)` is equivalent to `%D`.
> - `%(decorate:prefix=[,suffix=],separator=%x3B)` produces a list enclosed
>   in square brackets and separated by semicolons.

And:

> ### [`pretty`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f1f8a258567268974b9bbd012c33ad219a31aa0e): add pointer and tag options to `%(decorate)`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Andy Koppe</sup>

> Add pointer and tag options to `%(decorate)` format, to allow to override the " `->` " string used to show where HEAD points and the "`tag:` " string used to mark tags.

And:

> ### [`decorate`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1e63b34a449afd650b02ab19501e8ccf0c15816e): use commit color for HEAD arrow
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Andy Koppe</sup>

> Use the commit color instead of the HEAD color for the arrow or custom symbol in "`HEAD -> branch`" decorations, for visual consistency with the prefix, separator and suffix symbols, which are also colored with the commit color.
>
> This change was triggered by the possibility that one could choose to use the same symbol for the pointer and the separator options in `%(decorate)`, in which case they ought to be the same color.
>
> A related precedent is '`ls -l`', where the arrow for symlinks gets the default color rather than that of the symlink name.

`pretty-formats` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/f1f8a258567268974b9bbd012c33ad219a31aa0e/Documentation/pretty-formats.txt#L236-L244):

> For example, to produce decorations with no wrapping
> or tag annotations, and spaces as separators:
>
> `%(decorate:prefix=,suffix=,tag=,separator= )`

`pretty-formats` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/a58dd835e9536cf9e7adcd404d008a44d29af804/Documentation/pretty-formats.txt#L227-L236):

> ### `'%(decorate[:<options>])'`
>
> ref names with custom decorations.
> The `decorate` string may be followed by a
> colon and zero or more comma-separated options.
> Option values may contain
> literal formatting codes. These must be used for commas (`%x2C`) and closing
> parentheses (`%x29`), due to their role in the option syntax.
>
> - '`prefix=<value>`': Shown before the list of ref names.  Defaults to "`{nbsp}(`".
> - '`suffix=<value>`': Shown after the list of ref names.  Defaults to "`)`".
> - '`separator=<value>`': Shown between ref names.  Defaults to "`,{nbsp}`".
> - '`pointer=<value>`': Shown between HEAD and the branch it points to, if any.
>   Defaults to "`{nbsp}->{nbsp}`".
> - '`tag=<value>`': Shown before tag names. Defaults to "`tag:{nbsp}`".

Comment: See also [commit 92741d8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/92741d83c06b4cd0a15f43e23e4456604096cb0c), still with Git 2.43.