# How to print the output of GitK

Tags: git, gitk

I am using git v 1.7.4.msysgit.0 on windows.

I want to **print** the output of **gitK**(i mean physically on a *paper*)

I cant find a print menu there, google doesn't help here too.

Comment: what output do you need? if you need the graph, could you try `git log --graph`?

Comment: I need to print the graph using my printer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in "[Pretty git branch graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1058213/6309)", gitk has no print function (2009, still true in 2012 as far as I know).

The only solution being to capture part of the gitk window you are interested, but that won't capture *all* the history displayed by gitk.
Even a [non-free Git Windows client like SmartGit](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/features.html) doesn't seem to have that feature...

Answer (score 0):

```
git log --graph --all --decorate
```

should give you textual representation of your repo. Add --oneline if you want a condensed version.

Comment: Don't forget to set your `LESS` variable: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064361/unable-to-show-a-git-tree-in-terminal/1064431#1064431

Comment: @Adam I dont need a pretty log, i need the graphical print