# How to make git log cut long comments?

Tags: git, git-format

I have a git log alias that prints each commit as a single line. Since some people write far too long one-liners in the commit log, many commits wrap to a new line. How can I format the git log output to cut the comment after 50 characters?

I found this in the git-log man page but it will only pad short comments, not cut long ones.

```
%<(<N>[,trunc|ltrunc|mtrunc]): make the next placeholder take at least N columns,
  padding spaces on the right if necessary. Optionally truncate at the beginning (ltrunc),
  the middle (mtrunc) or the end (trunc) if the output is longer than N columns. Note that
  truncating only works correctly with N >= 2.
```

Answer (score 91, accepted):

It is not that clear in the documentation just which characters are needed but the following example cuts the subject line to 50 characters:

```
git log --oneline --format="%h %<(50,trunc)%s"
```

The format specification is `%<` and the arguments for that need to be in parentheses. In this case, 50 chars and truncate the excess.

For instance, performing this on the msysGit repository yields:

```
C:\src\msysgit>git log -n 5 --format="%h [%<(12,trunc)%aN] [%<(12,trunc)%cN] %<(50,trunc)%s"

218ed04 [Sebastian ..] [Sebastian ..] Merge pull request #154 from csware/tortoisegitp..
8a920b9 [Sven Stric..] [Sven Stric..] Installer: Detect TortoiseGitPlink from Tortoise..
448e125 [dscho       ] [dscho       ] Merge pull request #152 from csware/syscommand
db8d1bf [Sven Stric..] [Sven Stric..] Perl readline creates empty sys$command files if..
753d3d6 [Johannes S..] [Johannes S..] Git for Windows 1.8.5.2-preview20131230
```

Comment: Thanks! The "trunc" part was what I was looking for.

Comment: Thank you -it's been 30 mins trying to figure out this magic spell - fixed width :)

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  I have git --version => 1.7.10.4 (in Debian 7.9 Wheezy).  From http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log/1.8.3 I gather this feature was added in 1.8.3 (ie, the man page for 1.8.2.2 doesn't mention it).

Comment: This format string works for me with Git for Windows x64 2.6.1. Using the Windows cmd prompt I get the same layout shown above with truncation marks on the ends of truncated lines.

Comment: For me this doesn't just truncate long subjects to 50, it also pads short ones to make them 50

Comment: It would be nice to not pad. I can't figure out how to do it

Comment: @patthoyts How did you know that the angled brackets in the man page entry in `%<|(<N>)`, particularly those around N, `<N>`, were not part of the expression? Also, how did you know that the `|` in `%<|` was not to be used as part of the expression? I interpreted it as an OR, which confused me.

Answer (score 22):

Late to the party, but these options will do it too:

```
$ git config --global core.pager 'less -S'
```

or (e.g.)

```
$ echo $LESS
-R
$ export LESS=-RS
```

Comment: Works beautifully. Moreover, the line length adapts to the terminal width. From `less --help`: "-S ... chop long lines rather than wrapping". This makes graphs much more readable, e.g. when using `git log --oneline --decorate --all --graph`

Comment: beautiful! Is it possible to combine this with --no-pager, i.e. to use this one _and_ to output the result immediately to terminal without blocking on less?

Comment: Good to know, however, it truncates the entire line blindly, which results in unexpected behavior, such as this one: `git log --format="%h %ad \"%s\" (%an)" --date=short` (printing author at the end). Also, OP, like me, asks for truncating "comments" only.

Comment: If you want 'less' to exit when the output is less than a page long, add the `-E` (`--QUIT-AT-EOF`) option as well.

Comment: I can't thank you enough. This solves 90% of my headaches with git log formatting: "how do I get it to stop looking bad when X is too long??". Thanks!!

Answer (score 12):

## Truncate and pad the commit message only

As per other answers, the format placeholders `%<(50,trunc)%s` will print the commit message truncated at 50 characters. But that will also pad shorter values to the same, and there's no way to tell it not to.

If that suits you, then you're done. If not, another approach is needed.

## Truncate the entire line at terminal width

Also per other answers, you could configure `less -S` as the `core.pager` option globally or per-repository. This will trim the entire log string at the terminal width, avoiding wrapped lines.

But it will do that to **all Git commands!** (At least all the ones that produce paged output).

## Improvement - truncate only for that specific command

You can do this with the `-c` option, e.g. `git -c core.pager='less -S' log --graph --oneline`

Even better, set this up as an alias so you don't have to type it every time:

```
git config --global alias.graph "-c core.pager='less -S' \
 log --graph --oneline`
```

## Combining both

You can also combine this with formatting placeholders. Here's an example using the `--graph` flag, where the commit message is also padded/truncated to 50 characters, but since the `--graph` option creates a variable-width drawing of the commit graph, you need to combine both approaches. And you don't want to be typing this out every time:

```
git config --global alias.graph "-c core.pager='less -S' \
log --pretty='tformat:%C(bold cyan)%h %C(blue)%<(10,trunc)%aN \
%<(50,trunc)%C(white)%s %C(auto)%d %C(dim green)%ar' --graph"
```

Answer (score 4):

I put this into `~/bin/git-mylog`:

```
#!/bin/bash
COLS=$(tput cols)
git log --format="tformat:%>|(15)%C(auto)%h %Cgreen %<(20,trunc)%cn %C(auto) %<(15,trunc)%ar %<($((COLS-55)),trunc)%s" --graph
```

There's a bit going on here, but the guts of it is to use `tput cols` to get the terminal width and then do some arithmetic to truncate the comment width to the actual space available rather than a fixed width.

Comment: It looks nice with auto adjusting column width and colours....

Comment: I adapted this as an alias in my git config file: `lg = !git log --format=\"tformat:%>|(15)%C(auto)%h %Cgreen %<(20,trunc)%cn %C(auto) %<(15,trunc)%ar %<($(($(tput cols)-55)),trunc)%s\" --graph`

Answer (score 2):

```
git log --oneline
```

Will show stripped commit heads (has codes)

```
git log --pretty=oneline
```

Will show you full commit heads (has codes)

Comment: This works for 1.7 git, but not for 2.2 git.  I tried.  I think @patthoyts' suggested `--format` solution might be your only alternative for git 2.x.

Answer (score 2):

(I seem completely unable to format a comment appropriately so have posted this as an answer, but really is a comment to @patthoyts's response.)

What's lovely about `trunc` is that it pads, so you can use it like so:
`git log --pretty=format:"%ad %<(50,trunc)%s %h" --date=short --reverse`
to produce an easier (at least for my eyes) overview.

`$ git log --pretty=format:"%ad %<(50,trunc)%s %h" --date=short --reverse

2015-06-15 initial commit                                     5099ede
2015-06-16 Layout - Responsive grid added.                    6534242
2015-06-17 HTML - H1 / Title updated <title>Testpage</title.. 88ea464 
2015-06-18 Updating the Hotfix changes                        a8fbc47`

Tip - add an [alias](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases) of, say, trunc to make it easy on yourself.
`git config --global alias.trunc 'log --pretty=format:"%ad %<(50,trunc)%s %h"
--date=short --reverse'`

Answer (score 1):

The use of ellipsis is clarified with Git 2.40 (Q1 2023):

See [commit 540e7bc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/540e7bc477fc9bc491221075c0fade0722e63945), [commit b5cd634](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b5cd634d7a30074452c5aa3b0ce66ce794c4d565), [commit 63792c5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/63792c564c3a96007baf7ce876dea0a6f5f9f880), [commit 8bcb8f8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8bcb8f8e2282ff27f7ffd106eb2fb7bf982ff2d1), [commit d664a7a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d664a7ad20f9cb013f4c53654b76973612a89991) (19 Jan 2023) by [Philip Oakley (`PhilipOakley`)](https://github.com/PhilipOakley).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 4ac326f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4ac326f64f19037d25994b947e29268ae0e39e75), 30 Jan 2023)</sup>

> ### [`doc`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b5cd634d7a30074452c5aa3b0ce66ce794c4d565): `pretty-format`s describe use of ellipsis in truncation
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Philip Oakley</sup>

> Commit [a7f01c6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a7f01c6b4ddf9f2f6bdcb23fc7afb56695807cba) (`pretty`: support truncating in `%>`, 2013-04-19, Git v1.8.3-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e52e6f79ccc372825313890b96007985b8aa6e9c)) (`pretty`: support truncating in `%>`, `%<` and `%><`, 2013-04-19) added the use of ellipsis when truncating placeholder values.
>
> Show our 'two dot' ellipsis, and examples for the left, middle and right truncation to avoid any confusion as to which end of the string is adjusted.
> (cf justification and sub-string).

`pretty-formats` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b5cd634d7a30074452c5aa3b0ce66ce794c4d565/Documentation/pretty-formats.txt#L152-L154):

> truncate (with ellipsis '`..`') at the left `(ltrunc)` `..ft`,
> the middle `(mtrunc)` `mi..le`, or the end
> `(trunc)` `rig..`, if the output is longer than N columns.

That is what the `%C(blue)%<(10,trunc)%aN %<(50,trunc)%C(white)%s` would do.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to use the “reference” format[1] but with a truncated
summary. The problem with `$<()` and the other modifiers is that they are
used for *padding*, while I only want the truncation.

Note that I only want to truncate the summary and not the whole output
line.[2]

I didn't find a way to do this with git(1) formatting so I had to resort
to the usual ugly pipeline:

```
#/bin/sh
git log --date=short --pretty='format:%C(auto)%h (%<(50,trunc)%s, %ad)' $@ \
    | tr --squeeze-repeats ' ' | sed -e 's/ ,/,/g' | less --quit-if-one-screen
```

- Truncate to 50 width (50 ASCII characters)
- `tr --squeeze-repeats ' '` to get rid of run of whitespace, i.e. padding

  - The summary line could also contain runs of whitespace, but this is so
    unlikely that I don't care
- `sed -e 's/ ,/,/g'` to get rid of any remaining single-space in front of
  the comma (separating the summary and the date)
- `less --quit-if-one-screen` is meant to emulate the default git(1)
  treatment of output

As a Git alias (using the usual shell function pattern for positional
arguments):

```
logrefshort = "!f() { git log --date=short --pretty='format:%C(auto)%h (%<(50,trunc)%s, %ad)' $@ | tr --squeeze-repeats ' ' | sed -e 's/ ,/,/g' | less --quit-if-one-screen; }; f"
```

#### Example

```
$ git logrefshort --no-merges -20 origin/master
d4a83d07b8c (The tenth batch, 2023-09-18)
bda494f4043 (The ninth batch, 2023-09-14)
d6c51973e4a (The eighth batch, 2023-09-13)
9f892830d69 (completion(switch/checkout): treat --track and -.., 2023-09-08)
94e83dcf5b5 (The seventh batch, 2023-09-07)
aae8558b103 (grep: reject --no-or, 2023-09-07)
203573b0246 (rebase -i: fix adding failed command to the todo.., 2023-09-06)
405509cbd66 (rebase --continue: refuse to commit after failed.., 2023-09-06)
e032abd5a0b (rebase: fix rewritten list for failed pick, 2023-09-06)
f2b5f41eda5 (sequencer: factor out part of pick_commits(), 2023-09-06)
9f67899b41e (sequencer: use rebase_path_message(), 2023-09-06)
206a78d7108 (rebase -i: remove patch file after conflict reso.., 2023-09-06)
36ac861a305 (rebase -i: move unlink() calls, 2023-09-06)
11422f23e3e (doc/diff-options: fix link to generating patch s.., 2023-09-06)
256a94ef6c8 (var: avoid a segmentation fault when `HOME` is u.., 2023-09-04)
82af2c639c4 (sequencer: fix error message on failure to copy .., 2023-09-03)
2a63c79dae7 (grep: use OPT_INTEGER_F for --max-depth, 2023-09-02)
078c42531e8 (name-rev: use OPT_HIDDEN_BOOL for --peel-tag, 2023-09-02)
6d79cd8474b (ref-filter: sort numerically when ":size" is used, 2023-09-02)
0058b3d5eed (parse-options: mark unused parameters in noop ca.., 2023-08-31)
```

#### Notes

1. `git log --format=reference`. E.g.: aae8558b103 (grep: reject --no-or,
   2023-09-07)
2. But it's not like the rest of the format is terribly dynamic (unlike
   the summary). The only thing that can vary (before the year 10,000) is
   the abbreviated hash since the length depends on how many objects are
   in your database/repository.