# How can I get git log to limit the number of lines per commit message?

Tags: git

I'm using git log to read through commit messages, but some of them are super-long, containing backtraces and other things that I don't want to see. I'd like to see maybe the first 10 lines of the body for each commit. I've read through the documentation for git log (in particular --format), and there doesn't seem to be a way to do this.

Comment: git --oneline reduces it to oneline, you might find this link useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21830810/how-to-make-git-log-cut-long-comments

Answer (score 2):

You would need to process each git log entry.

Make a bash script called `git-logm` (that works even on Windows) with

```
#!/bin/bash
for ((i=0; i<=$1; i++))
do
    body=$(git log -1 --skip=$i --pretty=format:%B|head -4)
    echo "HEAD~$i $body"
done
```

Then a `git logm 5` would display 5 commits, each one with only the first 4 lines of their commit message.

Comment: I'm doing git log between two dates, so I don't think this would work for me.

Comment: @hexdreamer Sure: you just need to get the SHA1 for each commit between those two date, then request for the commit message as shown in the script (with a `| head -4`)

Comment: Seems roundabout, but I think I can make it work. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Now that I'm pushed to logging a single commit at a time, it's easier to just do:

git log -1 ${HASH} | head -c 1024

Answer (score 0):

I use this alias to get a quick view of all my commits, it is pretty convenient.  Add it to your .bashrc or .zshrc file.

```
alias glo='git log --oneline --decorate'
```

Sample Output:

```
1417fb7 (HEAD -> master, origin/master) Updated .gitignore
5a22485 Add sample BG PDF docs
423131e Fixing the .gitignore file.
633d7de Added some examples
ab752e4 Initial commit
960d841 Create 'Hello World' example to output PDF.
```

Comment: I'd like to get the subject and about 10 lines of the body, so I don't think this would work for me.