# Truncate colored lines after N printable chars

Tags: bash, git, tmux, watch

I live inside a `tmux` session. When surfing and hammering `git` branches, I usually keep track of my recent history in a side pane with an alias that expands to:

```
watch -cn 0.5 'git log --graph --oneline --all --color=always --decorate'
```

**Problem**: long lines get wrapped and break the lovely colored graph, destabilizing me!

**Workarounds**:

- a bad one is to truncate the uncolored `git-log` output:

  ```
  watch -cn 0.5 'git log --graph --oneline --all --decorate | cut -c -$COLUMNS'
  ```

  but I absolutely need the colors to not lose my HEAD;
- worse one is to keep colors and let `cut` count non-printable characters too:

  ```
  watch -cn 0.5 'git log --graph --oneline --all --color=always --decorate | cut -c -$COLUMNS'
  ```

  which means lines are badly truncated, and sometimes even joined.

**Question**: is there any standard tool which can truncate lines after N printable chars?

I would avoid a self written `cut`-like solution, because of portability mainly.

Comment: That's one interesting problem you have there! Can you try and see, when you add `--format="%h %<(50,trunc)%s"` to your `git` parameters, if it will aleviate the pain a little bit. *Note* this is just a sample way to represent the message taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21830810/how-to-make-git-log-cut-long-comments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found:

```
alias gw='watch -cn 0.5 "git log --graph --oneline --all --color=always --decorate | grep -Eo \"^(([[:cntrl:]]\[[0-9;]{,4}m)*[[:print:]]){,\$COLUMNS}\""'
```