# Git: List the number of branches merged to Master but not on Release branch

Tags: git, repository, git-merge, git-diff

I am using `Git` repository. I have a `Release` branch which is behind `Master` branch. I normally merged development branches to the `Master` and only QA verified branches merged to Release. Is there anyway to list out the branches which have been merged to `Master` but not merged to `Release` branch? This way it will be easy for me to list out which are the branches have been merged to `Master` also merged to `Release`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can list the merged branches with `git branch --merged <branch name>`. So in your case you'd run

```
$ git branch --merged Master
... branches ...
$ git branch --merged Release
... branches ...
```

and look for branches that appear in the first output but not the second. I'm sure it's possible to do a oneliner but I'm no shell guru.

Depending on whether you want to include remote branches or list only remote branches you have to use the `-a` or `-r` flags respectively.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
git log --graph --oneline --all
```

Look for the merges in between this output.

For more information read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064361/unable-to-show-a-git-tree-in-terminal) question as well.