# wach all activitys of repository

Tags: git, projects-and-solutions

I am doing to the project and need , show all events ( pull , push , meges) in a branch in local directory.

My problem , in my project modified any files and know , if i execute any pull or action , what can modified the project .

I try whit :

```
git fetch && git log origin <branch>
```

and this ,

```
git log --graph --oneline --all
```

[Stack overflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064361/unable-to-show-a-git-tree-in-terminal)

but , i need any more detailed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with git log you have more and more option for example to define the output format and Controlling the display of entries with --pretty

```
git log --pretty=oneline --since='5 minutes ago'

git log --all --pretty=format:"%h %cd %s (%an)" --since='7 days ago'
```

[Git History](https://githowto.com/history)

otherwise using Gitlab or github you have a beautiful UI to display dashboard more detailed