# How to enter git project midway and know tree structure

Tags: git

I understand the workings of git for the most part and it really helps to visualize the tree structure of my working tree and the remote tree. I can do this fairly well if I develop the tree myself and maintain the remote tree. But what if I enter a project midway through and have no idea of the history of the remote tree? What commands can I run after I `git clone` the repo to determine what the history looks like and what I will be changing when I make commits and want to push?

Comment: If you are okay not using git command line, you can download source tree which gives a detailed representation of what it looks like.

Comment: @BradenBrown how do I do that?

Comment: Here is a link to the website https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/ once you have it downloaded, go to file > open. It will bring up an explorer, navigate to the project you want to manage then click 'select folder'

Comment: @BradenBrown Unfortunately I can't use that because of privacy concerns

Comment: Check out this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064361/unable-to-show-a-git-tree-in-terminal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this,

```
git log --graph --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit
```

or use the following command taken from this [article](https://coderwall.com/p/4-itow/nice-terminal-git-tree-graph).

```
git log --graph --full-history --all --color --date=short --pretty=format:"%Cred%x09%h %Creset%ad%Cblue%d %Creset %s %C(bold)(%an)%Creset"
```