# when git create tree?

Tags: git, git-commit

I've got three files with me:

```
git add .
```

And

```
git commit -m "bla blah blah"
```

Unfortunately, I don't see one, git tree.
When git create tree? 
There is a rule for this?

with:

```
$ git cat-file -p master^{tree}
```

i only see:

blobs

```
[Ubuntu-1604-xenial-64-minimal]mars~/git29012019[0]> git cat-file -p master^{tree}
100644 blob 39f7cb850446bb67a198a4df484aa627b4907be4    hallo.txt
100644 blob 7fcd1b9ac1bf7d3544297b177de51bb1fe4891dc    heute.txt
100644 blob d2606d4f699dafaf905b1645dcd04e767623622b    meins.txt
```

when is a tree created? 
when git create tree?
Thanks

Comment: Please explain what you're really asking here. There is an internal data structure known as a tree object that holds the directory structure of the repository, related to commits, is this what you're asking about? If so then tree objects are created whenever you commit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to show a Git tree in terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064361/unable-to-show-a-git-tree-in-terminal)

Comment: Maybe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064361/unable-to-show-a-git-tree-in-terminal) will help.

Comment: This is a different tree, a tree of commits. The OP asked about [tree object](https://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Git-Objects#_tree_objects) attached to commit.

Answer (score 2):

Git create the tree objects when you do a `git commit`.

Before that, the tree objects are temporary stored in the index file and its hash is filled in the commit object later when you create it.

Comment: Git doesn't create a tree when you run `git add` but it creates a tree from the index on running `git commit`.