# How to build a tag tree in GIT?

Tags: git, branch, git-tag

As frequent GIT user, I love `git log --graph` as much as I love `git tag`. I was made responsible for a large GIT repository with too many branches and tags and I am proceeding too slowly with the [sisyphusian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sisyphus) work of reducing those numbers.

It would be extremely helpful is to have a **tag tree graph**, just like a usual commit graph, but **only with those branches which have tags** on it. I would also need the hash of each tagged commit (and ideally also the time-stamp and author).

I searched a lot, but I never found anything like what I described.

#### Some references (of ever so many)

- [Git: How to find out on which branch a tag is?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15806448/git-how-to-find-out-on-which-branch-a-tag-is)
- [Unable to show a Git tree in terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064361/unable-to-show-a-git-tree-in-terminal)

Comment: `git log --graph --oneline --simplify-by-decoration`; see [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_pretty_formats) for `--pretty:tformat=...` option instead of `--oneline` to specify exactly what to include and how it should look.

Comment: Uups, that was easy. Thanks! It is a shame that I did not know that before. Since which version is that possible?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Amadan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/240443/amadan) pointed out, I should have dived deeper into the [git-log documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) in the most recent version. The solution is simply to include the `--simplify-by-decoration` flag. Altogether, I ended up with the following

```
git log --graph --simplify-by-decoration --pretty=format:'%C(yellow)%h %ad %an%Cgreen%d %Creset%s' --date=short
```

The [official formatting documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_pretty_formats) explains all the details of `--pretty=format:'...'`, the most important parts are

- `%h` = abbreviated commit hash
- `%an` = author name
- `%ad` = author date
- `%s` = subject

If want something to memorize, just use

```
git log --graph --simplify-by-decoration
```

This gives you an output without of commit hash and git-tag only.