# how to get a graphic representation of git branches on windows that really shows the topology of the repository?

Tags: git, graph, commit, topology

My last question was closed because apparently is a duplicate and had been responded several times. However, none of the answers mentioned ([Unable to show a Git tree in terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064361/unable-to-show-a-git-tree-in-terminal), [Pretty git branch graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057564/pretty-git-branch-graphs), [Visualizing branch topology in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838873/visualizing-branch-topology-in-git)) resolves my question. 
Among those there is a very complete answer, but is for git on Linux; there are many others that give complex commands, but they do not show what I'd like to see; and there are others referring tools to paint a contrived topology (not one of a real repository).

What I'd like to know is if there is, on Windows, something (a tool, command, etc) that shows me a graph like this:

```
c1 <--- c2 <-- c6  master 
         |
         --- c3 <-- c4  branch 1
              |
              --- c7 <-- c8 branch 2
```

or, if it's, as a matter of fact, impossible to get.

All commands (as complex as they are), or tools like gitk, for a topology like the above show something like this:

[image]

From where I can not know that, for example, branch 2 was created from a commit on branch 1 and is following a different development path.

Thank you.

Comment: have you tried Atlassian's Sourcetree?

Answer (score 0):

I have Some Tool which will help you to show git history in UI. as you want.

1. [GitAhead](https://gitahead.github.io/gitahead.com/)
2. [SublimeMerge](https://www.sublimemerge.com/)
3. [SmartGit](https://www.filehorse.com/download-smartgit/)
4. [GitCola](https://git-cola.github.io/downloads.html)

Comment: Thank you, Krishna. Unfortunately, none of those tools you suggested shows the things as I'd like. I tried GitAhead and SublimeMerge: those show a prettier representation than the decorated git log, but do not let me know when a branch is created from another (I can not paste images here to show). SmartGit was detected as a threat by my antivirus, so I didn't tried it.

Comment: you can check via git commits history,  it will show when the branch is created and from where.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very nice Visual Code Extension for this - https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mhutchie.git-graph