# Understanding the git graph

Tags: git, git-branch, git-log

I used the `git log --graph --all` command to visualise my commit/branch history. However whilst I understand what most of what the graph shows there are some parts of the branch visualisation I am having difficulty interpreting.

The branches that I am having difficulty interpreting are:

a) Commit `309a287`

b) Commit `3f7475`

c) The interpretation of `)` in e9415f

I am also slightly puzzled by why there seems to be three branches (three vertical parallel lines) as I only ever had a master branch and one additional branch at the same time.

```
|
| * commit 88531a7dc85d030016296a51c5c433b72c7186c5 (refs/stash)
|/| Merge: c501f9f 631678b
| | Author: 
| | Date:   Wed May 20 17:01:59 2020 +0100
| |
| |     On blackforest: ddd
| |
| * commit 631678b558576418c21496712db524eb86a755ec
|/  Author: 
|   Date:   Wed May 20 17:01:59 2020 +0100
|
|       index on blackforest: c501f9f induced typo
|
* commit c501f9fc6b817541d8cb6a466c77b8d84231afcb (origin/blackforest)
| Author: 
| Date:   Sun May 17 18:53:59 2020 +0100
|
|     induced typo
|
| *   commit e9415f49f953ca4fe53bd9631e4afea94c3ba4ba (HEAD -> master, origin/master
)
| |\  Merge: 9a1ff1f 3f74752
| | | Author: 
| | | Date:   Sun May 17 18:51:40 2020 +0100
| | |
| | |     Merge branch 'master' of
| | |
| | *   commit 3f7475269c1134aef39a06f13ae11d74c9496542
| | |\  Merge: 309a287 3d41b51
| |_|/  Author:
|/| |   Date:   Sun May 17 18:46:19 2020 +0100
| | |
| | |       Merge pull request #1 from 
| | |
| | |       enhanced emoticon
| | |
* | | commit 3d41b51c8157abe38d251e065ad33b3d265d332c
| | | Author: 
| | | Date:   Sun May 17 18:42:00 2020 +0100
| | |
| | |     enhanced emoticon
| | |
| * | commit 9a1ff1fa645e8390ab26f751dbf1b716e15b0df6
| |/  Author: 
| |   Date:   Sun May 17 18:50:09 2020 +0100
| |
| |       capitalised a
| |
| *   commit 309a287f9c39d219d719efbcc872a176f7644b19
| |\  Merge: dafe938 806e855
| |/  Author: 
|/|   Date:   Sun May 17 17:42:46 2020 +0100
| |
| |       Merge branch 'blackforest'
| |
* | commit 806e8558cd7b24658a998b2ee5d19500e608b77d
| | Author: 
| | Date:   Sun May 17 17:06:10 2020 +0100
| |
| |     new common
| |
* | commit a5e386a55389a6435a050be9981ea97011449783
| | Author: 
| | Date:   Sun May 17 17:32:26 2020 +0100
| |
| |     Edited firstfile to reflect new branch name
| |
| * commit dafe938bcfbdfe6eaf62d5f446637e6f5d594015
|/  Author: 
|   Date:   Sun May 17 17:06:10 2020 +0100
|
```

Comment: I never use graph with full commit messages. Try `git log --graph --oneline --all`, maybe that makes the output clearer. `)` is simply a continuation from the line above (`(HEAD -> master, origin/master`…`)`)

Comment: have you tried https://gitahead.github.io/gitahead.com/
...other GUIs are available...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61905276/how-to-get-a-graphic-representation-of-git-branches-on-windows-that-really-shows

Answer (score 15, accepted):

(I find your question a little unfocused, in that I'm not sure what particular aspects of `git log --graph` output here are confusing, so this is going to be long, I'm afraid: I'll try to cover everything important.)

[knittl noted in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61936264/understanding-the-git-graph#comment109545097_61936264) that the stray closing parenthesis is just a wraparound from a previous line.  Normally `git log` runs its output through a pager, and smart pagers can take care of this problem by giving you a left-and-right scrollable "window" over your text, so that the close parenthesis simply disappears off the right side of a Terminal window (or whatever terminal emulator you use).

With that out of the way, let's look specifically at `309a287` and `3f7475`, but start with this:

> I am also slightly puzzled by why there seems to be three branches (three vertical parallel lines) as I only ever had a master branch and one additional branch at the same time.

You had, apparently, two names: `master` and `blackforest`.  But you also had two different *repositories:*

> `Merge branch 'master' of [snipped]`

The snipped part would be a URL; this particular message, `Merge branch '<name>' of <url>` (which may end with `into <name>`) is the one that `git pull` cooks up when it passes a merge commit message on to `git merge`.<sup>1</sup>  So this `git log --graph` output implies that you ran `git pull` which invoked `git merge` on a commit it got from some other Git repository.

We can in fact see that commit: it is the second parent of merge commit `e9415f4...`.  So if we take just these four lines:

> ```
> | *   commit e9415f49f953ca4fe53bd9631e4afea94c3ba4ba (HEAD -> master, ori...
> ```

```
| |\  Merge: 9a1ff1f 3f74752
| | *   commit 3f7475269c1134aef39a06f13ae11d74c9496542
| | |\  Merge: 309a287 3d41b51
```

we can see it.  It's one of your own mystery commits, in this case, `3f74752...`.  Its commit message begins with `Merge pull request #1 from`.  GitHub and other similar hosting sites generate commits with such messages.

So, you—or someone else—must have made *this* commit on some web-hosting-site such as GitHub.  You or they must have made this commit in a repository hosted there.  That's a *second Git repository* and *it has its own branch names*, so depending on how many branch names it has, there could be thousands, or millions, of branches.

*Their* branches only affect *your* repository when you let them.  You have your Git call up their Git and get any new commits from them.  Your Git adds these commits to your repository database, which tries fairly hard to keep every commit it's ever seen.  If you then `git merge` one of *their* commits, you gain direct access, from your own branch name—whatever branch you're on right now—to this commit.

---

<sup>1</sup>Remember, `git pull` means *run `git fetch`, then run a second Git command.*  The second Git command defaults to `git merge`.  That `git merge` command needs a merge message sometimes—whenever it makes a true merge—and `git pull` supplies one, when the second command is `git merge`.  (If you tell `git pull` to run `git rebase` instead, no merge message is required so `git pull` doesn't supply one.)

---

#### Git is not really about branches

The way to understand what's going on is to realize that Git, in the end, really cares about *commits*.  It's not so concerned with branches.  It is not concerned at all with files, most of the time—files are just some nuisance thing that commits have.  Of course, we wouldn't use Git at all if it weren't for the files inside the commits, but that's just *us* that care about files: that's not Git.

Once we see that it's the *commits* that matter to Git, we can see how *branch names* enter the picture.  It is then possible—though still a bit of a leap—to go from *branch names* to the fundamental question of what we actually mean by *branch* (see [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452)):

**A *branch name* in Git is a pointer to one specific commit.**  That is, it identifies one commit hash ID by name.  Other Git names, such as tag names, can do this same job, but branch names have one other special property: they *move automatically*, so that they always name the *last* commit in the branch.

In other words, the hash ID stored under a branch name *is* the last commit in the branch, by definition.  Then we just need to realize one more key thing: **Each commit stores the hash ID of some set of previous commits.**

The commits themselves are what form the graph.  Given some commit—as identified by some hash ID—Git can reach into that commit and extract, from that commit, the hash IDs of its immediate predecessor.  Or, for a merge commit, instead of one immediate predecessor, we have two.<sup>2</sup>  Either way, though, we end up with something like this:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

where `H` is the hash ID of the *last* commit in some chain.  Or maybe a chain ends at a merge commit:

```
...--I--J
         \
          M
         /
...--K--L
```

or has some additional commits afterwards:

```
...--I--J
         \
          M--N
         /
...--K--L
```

but in all cases, a chain *ends* at a *branch tip commit*, and it does so because a *branch name* points to that commit:

```
...--G--H   <-- master
         \
          I--J   <-- feature
```

*All* the commits up through the tip are on the branch, so in this case, commits up through `H` are on both `master` and `feature`, and `I--J` are on `feature` alone.

---

<sup>2</sup>A merge commit can actually have more than two parents, but we don't really need to worry about this here.

---

#### `git log` has to linearize things

Suppose we have a graph like this:

```
...--I--J
         \
          M--N   <-- master
         /
...--K--L
```

where `N` is the newest commit and its parent `M` is a merge that has two parents `J` and `L`.  By drawing this graph sideways, with the newest commits towards the right, we can show that any work done on the upper or lower rows of commits (`I-J` and `K-L` respectively) isn't strictly ordered with respect to the *other* row, but only within its own row.

Note that Git finds commits by starting at the tip commit, as found by the branch name—here, that's `master` which leads to commit `N`—and then working backwards.  As it works backwards, `git log` needs to move from each commit to its parent or parents.  From `N` to `M` this is easy, as there is only one parent.  From `M` back, though, `git log` really *should* visit both commits `J` and `L` simultaneously ... but it can't.

Specifically, `git log` has to print things out vertically.  The *tip* commit `N` will come out first, and hence be at the top of our Terminal window.  Below that will be commit `M`.  If `git log` could do what I am about to draw, it might then show the left and right "sides" of the merge like this:

```
     N    <information>
     |
     M    <information>
    / \
   J   L   <information about J> <information about L>
   |   |
   I   K   <information about I> <information about K>
   :   :
```

But `git log` can't do that, so it approximates.  It picks whichever of commits `J` and `L` has a later *committer date* and puts that out first:

```
     N    <information>
     |
     M    <information>
    / \
   |   L    <information about L>
   |   |
   J   |    <information about J>
   :   :
```

This is pretty close to the actual output, but it's slightly different:

```
N  <information about N>
|
M  <information about M>
|\
| L  <information about L>
| |
J |  <information about J>
: :
```

and that's what you mostly see in your own `git log` output.

#### "First-parent" is significant

The last thing that might seem especially peculiar is this:

> ```
> | *   commit 309a287f9c39d219d719efbcc872a176f7644b19
> | |\  Merge: dafe938 806e855
> | |/  Author: 
> |/|   Date:   Sun May 17 17:42:46 2020 +0100
> | |
> | |       Merge branch 'blackforest'
> | |
> * | commit 806e8558cd7b24658a998b2ee5d19500e608b77d
> ```

Why did `git log` do this funky *jut out to the right, then swing back to the left* thing?  That is, why draw this:

```
| *
| |\
| |/
|/|
: :
```

when:

```
| *
|/|
: :
```

would likely do?  [**Edit, May 2022:** Modern Git will do this now.  I'm not sure which version of Git got smarter here.]

The answer here is that in Git, the *first-parent-ness* of a merge commit is significant.  In my own horizontal drawings:

```
...--I--J
         \
          M--N   <-- master
         /
...--K--L
```

I try to make it look like there's nothing more important about the `J <-M` connection than there is about the `L <-M` connection.  That's because in one sense, there *isn't* anything more important here: both `J` and `L` are parents of `M`, and when we made the merge, if we didn't use `-X ours` or `-X theirs`, there wasn't anything more important about either commit while resolving conflicts, either.

But the *first* parent of any merge commit is special, for the same reason that the *first and only* parent of any normal, non-merge commit is special: it's the direct lineage, backwards, of the commits we made, one commit at a time.

Consider how we make normal everyday non-merge commits.  We start with:

```
git checkout master
```

which gets us something like this:

```
...--G--H   <-- master (HEAD)
```

That is, the special name `HEAD` is now *attached to* the branch name `master`.  The *current branch* is now `master`.  The *current commit* is the tip commit *of* `master`, i.e., commit `H`: it is commit `H`'s content that we have in our work-tree, that we can work on.

If we do in fact do some work, and `git add` and `git commit`, we get a new commit, which we'll call `I`.  The new commit has commit `H` as its parent:

```
...--G--H   [master used to point to H]
         \
          I
```

and the final act of `git commit` is to write `I`'s actual hash ID, whatever that is, into the *name* `master`:

```
...--G--H   [master used to point to H]
         \
          I   <-- master (HEAD)
```

after which we can just draw these as a straight line again:

```
...--G--H--I   <-- master (HEAD)
```

As we repeat this process, the branch grows.  Here's that ambiguous word, *branch*, again: this time it means *a series of commits ending at a particular designated commit* **and** *the name `master`*, both at the same time, [depending on what we want it to mean at that moment](https://www.fecundity.com/pmagnus/humpty.html).

```
...--G--H--I--J   <-- master (HEAD)
```

If we now have some other branch:

```
...--G--H--I--J   <-- master (HEAD)
         \
          K----L   <-- feature
```

and run `git merge feature`, we get a new merge commit `M`.  The merge commit extends `master` because `HEAD` is attached to `master`:

```
...--G--H--I--J--M   <-- master (HEAD)
         \      /
          K----L   <-- feature
```

We could do this even if the name `feature` did not exist, as long as we could *find* commit `L` somehow.  That is, if we made commits `K` and `L` like this, then *deleted the name `feature` entirely* while making sure Git doesn't clean out the commits, we would have:

```
...--G--H--I--J   <-- master (HEAD)
         \
          K----L   [unnamed]
```

We could then run `git merge hash-of-L` and we would get the same result as before:

```
...--G--H--I--J--M   <-- master (HEAD)
         \      /
          K----L
```

Commit `L` has now become find-able by name again: it is the *second* parent of `M`.

More commonly, we might merge `feature` into `master`, producing `M`, then *delete the name `feature`*, to leave us in this same state.

#### Putting this all together

**Git does not care (much) about the names.**  Git only cares about the commits.  Git *uses* the names to *find* tip commits, and then works backwards; and if that can find any given commit, the commit stays.

But **in all cases, the first-parent-ness of a commit matters**.  For ordinary (non-merge) commits, the first parent is the only parent.  For merge commits, the first parent is the commit that *was* the tip, at the time we made the merge.

If we use `git log --first-parent`—with or without `--graph`—`git log` will, whenever it reaches a merge commit, *ignore all but the first parent*.  That is, given the graph fragment ending at merge commit `M`, `git log` without `--first-parent` will show:

- commit M; then
- commit J or L, in some order; then
- commit I or J or K or L, in some order, but skipping whichever commit it showed before;

and so on, until it has shown all commits that can be found by starting at `M` and working backwards.  It shows each commit one at a time, and the *order* it uses is something you can control, with various *sort the commits in `git log` output* options:

```
git log --author-date-order
```

uses the author-date timestamp instead of the committer-date timestamp (each commit has two date-and-time stamps in it).  Or:

```
git log --topo-order
```

uses an ordering that `git log --graph` requires, so `git log --graph` turns that ordering constraint on.

Adding `--first-parent` tells `git log` that when it steps back from commit `M`, it should look *only* at commit `J`, not commit `L`.  Commit `L` is the *second* parent, so `git log` should just throw it out of the list of commits to visit.  The result will be that `git log --first-parent master` will show `M`, then `J`, then `I`, then `H`, then `G`, and so on.

The reason for this particular well-controlled order is that `git log` walks the graph *one commit at a time* using a [*priority queue*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue).  You give `git log` some starting commit(s):

```
git log master
```

or:

```
git log --all
```

for instance, and `git log` figures out the hash ID(s) of these commits.  If you gave one branch name like `master`, that names one commit: the tip commit of that branch.  The queue now has one entry in it.

Then, as long as the queue is not empty, `git log` executes a loop:

1. Take the front (highest priority) entry off the queue.
2. Show that commit.  (There are options to maybe *not* show it here, but we did not use any of these options.)
3. If we haven't shown them yet and they are not already in the queue, place this commit's parent(s) into the queue.  With the `--first-parent` option, place only the *first* parent into the queue.
4. Repeat.

So our `git log master` with `--first-parent` never has more than one commit in the queue at any time: it starts with one, removes it to get to zero, shows the commit, and puts in the one parent.  Without `--first-parent`, it starts with one commit—`M`—in the queue, removes it (queue empty), shows `M`, and inserts *two* commits into the queue: `J` and `L`.  The priority now matters.

The default priority is that later-committer-date commits have higher priority.  If we made commit `L` later than we made commit `J`, the next commit we'll show is `L`.  That's true whether or not `L` is the first or second parent.

The `git log --graph` code will make sure that the *line* connecting from `M` to `L`—its second parent—starts by going down-and-right [**edit**: or down-and-left now].  That's what we see here:

> ```
> | *   commit 309a287f9c39d219d719efbcc872a176f7644b19
> | |\  Merge: dafe938 806e855
> | |/  Author: 
> |/|   Date:   Sun May 17 17:42:46 2020 +0100
> | |
> | |       Merge branch 'blackforest'
> | |
> * | commit 806e8558cd7b24658a998b2ee5d19500e608b77d
> ```

The connector from `309a287...` to `806e855...` starts by going down and right, then doubles back over to join the left-side line.  The *second* parent of `309a287...` is `806e855...`.  (The *first* parent is `dafe938...`.)

The line reaching down to `806e855...` comes from commit `3d41b51...`, which is an ordinary one-parent commit.  *That* commit was found from commit `c501f9fc...`, which is also an ordinary one-parent commit, and is—or at least *was*, the last time your Git checked—the tip commit of branch `blackforest` in the Git repository over at `origin` (on GitHub or wherever).

(Your graph is cluttered slightly with the two commits made by `git stash`, as well.  These commits are not on any *branch*, but are reachable via the name `refs/stash`.  Note that one of them is technically a merge commit—but `git merge` did not make this commit; `git stash` made it; and if you treat it as if it were an ordinary merge, most Git commands won't make good sense from it, as they'll assume `git merge` made it.  Only `git stash` itself knows how to take this one apart later.)

Comment: This is a fabulous write up, thank you!